# Implement Shamir's Secret Sharing reconstruction

Tags: code-golf, cryptography, polynomials

[Shamir's secret sharing scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) is a simple way of protecting a secret by splitting it into several parts needed to reconstruct it.

Your task is to implement Shamir's Secret Sharing reconstruction over the [Finite Field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) defined by the prime `1928049029`. If you have any doubts about what this means, just ask or see Finite Field & [Finite Field Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic) in wikipedia (more resources below).

### Input

Input is done using stdin. First comes an integer `k`, then k lines follow. Each of these lines contains a pair of integers `x y` that represent a secret. In other words `f(x) = y` in the original polynomial that was used to construct the secrets.

The number of secrets given is always enough to construct the corresponding secret.

### Output

Output to stdout the reconstructed secret.

### Examples

**Input:**

```
5         
1 564797566
2 804114535
4 1354242660
6 1818201132
7 503769263
```

**Output:**

```
1234
```

**Input:**

```
7
1 819016192
2 1888749673
3 1737609270
4 365594983
5 1628804870
6 1671140873
7 492602992
```

**Output:**

```
456457856
```

### Resources

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing)

[Paper](http://szabo.best.vwh.net/secret.html)

[Finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) Source: Wikipedia

[Finite field arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic) Source: Wikipedia

[Lagrange polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) Source: Wikipedia

[Chapter on Finite field arithmetic](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aCmQSTh2WDeIJ%3awww.springer.com/%3FSGWID%3D2-102-45-110359-4+finite+field+arithmethics&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESikdA6tzTfrWAdoudGolj3rW6eFLQGVnUSdnS3Yl_viLtytnZQUs868ulwqWbdYUCecDNUMQSVou0ItLhhJstUITdUsBbokZuArnDGoB5MzcuAPdz-iODPRYdX0OPRB0kxa2ttL&sig=AHIEtbTNiW7G-8mbUMBt1YEcLTiRDy7eXw)

Answer (score 5):

#### bash, 271 chars

```
r(){
[ ${1/0/} ]&&{ r $(($2%$1)) $1;((t=u,u=v-$2/$1*u,v=t));}
}
read
((N=1928049029,n=0))
while read x[$n] y[$n]
do((n++))
done
for((i=n;z=(z+l)%N,i--;))do
for((j=n,l=y[i];j--;))do
((u=0,v=1,d=x[j]-x[i],M=N+d))
r M N
[ ${d/0/} ]&&((l=l*x[j]%N*(u+N)%N))
done
done
echo $z
```

The newlines could be replaced in most cases with semicolons, but I don't think there's any unnecessary whitespace.

(I hadn't realised before today that bash's integers are 64-bit - very helpful).

For bash the recursive GCD (exploiting global state) seems to be more compactible than the iterative one. This is mostly straightforward; the interesting trick is `[ ${d/0/} ]&&foo` which is effectively `if [ $d -ne 0 ];then foo;fi`

Comment: Nice! I never expected to see a bash answer to this problem. +1

Comment: @Juan, I started doing it in Perl, and got fed up with having to force it to do integer division rather than float. And I know bash better anyway, so it involves less beating of head against wall.

Answer (score 3):

199 characters in Octave:

```
m=@(x)mod(x,1928049029);[d,l]=scanf('%d');c=d(1);e=repmat(int64(d(2:2:l)),1,c);[_,b]=gcd(e-e',1928049029*ones(c));b=eye(c)+m(e.*b);x=b(1,:);for i=2:c;x=m(x.*b(i,:));end;disp(m(sum(m(x'.*d(3:2:l)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Golfscript, <strike>114 112 111 110 109</strike> 65 (86) chars

If you don't care about getting results this week, 65 chars suffice:

```
~](;2/0\:X{~\.X{0=}%^\{\.@- 1928049029:P.,\@{@*\%(!}++?**}+/+P%}/
```

But if you're looking for efficiency, it's slightly longer at 86 chars:

```
~](;2/0\:X{~\.X{0=}%^\{\[.0](@-[1928049029:P%P]{.~/{\.(;@@~@*-+\}+2*.1=}do;0=*}+/+P%}/
```

This is dissected in far more detail than I want to repeat here [on my blog](http://www.cheddarmonk.org/golfscriptblog/2011/10/code-dissection-secret-sharing.html).

---

Mainly not my work, but cribbing heavily from Nabb gives 47 chars:

```
n%(!\:A{~A{~;.3$- 1928049029:N((?1or**}/\/+N%}/
```

Note: I've only reasoned about this code: trying to run it would be pointless given the length of time and amount of memory it would use.

Answer (score 3):

### Golfscript - <s>52</s> 46 (67)

A brute force approach for modular inverses in 46 characters. Repeatedly computes a^(N-2) with arbitrary precision integers.

```
n%(!\:A{~A{~;.3$-.!+1928049029:N((?**}/\/+N%}/
```

Implementing the extended Euclidean algorithm only costs us an additional 15 characters.

```
n%(!\:A{~A{~;.3$-:|!1\1928049029:N{@2$|3$/*-\|\:|%.}do;;**}/\/+N%}/
```

This code is fully detailed on my [blog post](http://golfscript.blogspot.com/2011/10/code-golf-shamirs-secret-sharing.html), including some alternatives for computing the modular multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Nice, but I think there are still at least two chars to be saved. Replace `{*N%2<}` with `{*N%1=}` as in the blog and you can ditch the `(;` after `N,`. But then for the performance-is-irrelevant entry you can use Fermat's little theorem without bothering about the modular side of the exponentiation - just leave that for the final tidy - so recip becomes `N((?`.

Comment: @Peter: `{*N%1=}+` will miss the case with the denominator zero, which would take at least 3 characters to handle. Good catch on simply doing x^(N-2) though, we can actually get 46 characters using this.

Answer (score 2):

**Lua 444 Chars**

Works for the example on the wiki page

```
3
2 1942
4 3402
5 4414
```

But somehow does not work for the examples here on this page. If anyone can find the error?

Non-golfed version:

```
-- Reconstruct shamir secret
-- convention, poly = {[0]=a0,a1,...,an}
i=io.read
f=math.fmod
w=1928049029
k=i():match"%d+"
x={} -- Will contain X values
y={} -- Will contain Y values
p={} -- will contain lagrange polynomials

-- Read data
for j=0,k-1 do
    x[j],y[j]=i():match("(%d+) (%d+)")
    print(j,x[j],y[j])
end
-- Multiplication and scaling function
function mul(p,q,s)
    -- multiply polies
    r={} -- poly to be returned
    for k=0,#p do 
        for l=0,#q do
            r[l+k]=r[l+k] or 0 -- if the coeff for degree l+k of x doesn't exist, put 0
            p[k]=p[k] or 0 -- if p hasn't got a coeff for x^k
            q[l]=q[l] or 0 -- idem for q
            r[l+k]=(r[l+k]+s*p[k]*q[l]%w -- calculate increment for coeff for x^(l+k) 
        end
    end
    -- Debugging
    io.write"Multiplied "
    printPoly(p)
    io.write"With       "
    printPoly(q)
    io.write("And scaling factor ",tostring(s),"\n")
    io.write"Yielding   "
    printPoly(r)
    return r
end

function printPoly(p) -- "Pretty" printing of the polynomial
    for k=#p,1,-1 do
        io.write(tostring(p[k] or 0),"x^",tostring(k),"+")
    end
    io.write(p[0])
    io.write"\n"
end
function egcd(a,b)
    if a == 0 then
        return b, 0, 1
    else
        local g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
        return g, x - math.floor(b / a) * y, y
    end
end

function inv(a,m)
    a=a>=0 and a or a+m
    local g,x,y = egcd(a,m)
    if g== 1 then
        return x%m
    else
        print(a,"has no inverse mod",m)
    end
end


-- generate lagrange polynomials
for j=0,#x do
    print("j=",j,"*********")
    for m=0,k-1 do
        if m~=j then -- if m==j, continue
            p[j]=p[j]or{[0]=1} -- if this poly doesn't exist, take 1
            p[j]=mul( p[j], {[0]=-x[m],1},inv(x[j]-x[m],w))-- multiply with (x-x_m)/(x_j-x_m)
            io.write"---------------------------------\n"
        end
    end
end
r=0 -- Result for x^0
for k=0,#p do
    print("l_"..k)
    printPoly(p[k]) -- print l_k
    r=r+f(y[k]*p[k][0],w) -- add coeff for x^0 to result
end
print("Secret was",f(r,w)) -- display result
```

Golfed (not using finite field), 444 chars:

```
i=io.read f=math.fmod w=1928049029 k=i():match"%d+"x={}y={}p={}for j=0,k-1 do x[j],y[j]=i():match("(%d+) (%d+)")end
function mul(p,q,s)r={}for k=0,#p do for l=0,#q do r[l+k]=r[l+k]or 0 p[k]=p[k]or 0 q[l]=q[l]or 0 r[l+k]=f(r[l+k]+s*p[k]*q[l],w)end end return r end
for j=0,#x do for m=0,k-1 do if m~=j then p[j]=p[j]or{[0]=1}p[j]=mul(p[j],{[0]=-x[m],1},1/(x[j]-x[m]))end end end r=0 for k=0,#p do r=r+f(y[k]*p[k][0],w)end
print(f(r,w))
```

Comment: The Wikipedia example doesn't use a finite field, which is really a shame, that would have been a lot more instructive. That is most likely the source of your error.

Answer (score 2):

#### Java, <strike>435</strike> 407 chars

```
import java.util.*;public class G{public static void main(String[]args){Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);int i,k,n=s.nextInt();long N=1928049029L,x[]=new long[n],y[]=new long[n],z=0,l,c;for(i=n;i-->0;){x[i]=s.nextInt();y[i]=s.nextInt();}for(i=n;i-->0;){l=y[i];for(long j:x)if(x[i]!=j){c=1;for(long a=N+j-x[i],b=N,d=0,t;b>0;){t=d;d=c-a/b*d;c=t;t=b;b=a%b;a=t;}l=l*j%N*(c+N)%N;}z+=l;}System.out.println(z%N);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
import java.util.*;
public class G {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,k,n=s.nextInt();
        long N=1928049029L,x[]=new long[n],y[]=new long[n],z=0,l,c;
        for (i=n; i-->0;) {
            x[i]=s.nextInt();
            y[i]=s.nextInt();
        }
        for (i=n; i-->0;) {
            l=y[i];
            for (long j:x)
                if (x[i]!=j) {
                    // Extended Euclid algorithm - iterative version -
                    // to find the reciprocal of j-x[i] (mod N)
                    c=1;
                    for (long a=N+j-x[i], b=N, d=0, t; b>0;) {
                        t=d; d=c-a/b*d; c=t;
                        t=b; b=a%b; a=t;
                    }
                    l = l*j%N;
                    l = l*(c+N)%N;
                }
                z+=l;
        }
        System.out.println(z%N);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 183

```
p=1928049029
a#0=(1,0)
a#b=let(s,t)=b#mod a b in(t,s-div a b*t)
s d=sum[y*product[z*fst((z-x)#p)|[z,_]<-d,z/=x]|[x,y]<-d]
main=interact$show.(`mod`p).s.map(map read.words).tail.lines
```