# Polynomial extrapolation

Tags: code-golf, math, array

### Task

> Given a list of integers *a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, …, a<sub>k</sub>* (*k* ≥ 2) and a positive integer *m*, write a function or a complete program that calculates the next *m* numbers of the list. Assume that *a<sub>i</sub> = P(i)* where
>
> *P(x) = b<sub>k-1</sub> x<sup>k-1</sup> + b<sub>k-2</sub> x<sup>k-2</sup> + … + b<sub>0</sub>*
>
> is the unique polynomial of minimum order which fits the points.

### Description

#### Input

If the code is a function, input is given by an integer *k*, an array *a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, …, a<sub>k</sub>* and an integer *m*.

If the code is a program, input (through stdin) is given by space-separated *k a<sub>1</sub> a<sub>2</sub> … a<sub>k</sub> m*.

You can assume that *k* ≥ 2 and *m* > 0.

#### Calculation

(Of course, the code can calculate the result in different way, but the result should be same.)

Find the polynomial *P(x)* which satisfies *a<sub>i</sub> = P(i)* for all 1 ≤ *i* ≤ k and has a degree of (no more than) *k* - 1. For example, if a list is `1,2,3,4,5`, then *P(x) = x*. If a list is `1,4,9,16,25`, then *P(x) = x<sup>2</sup>*.

Then, calculate *a<sub>k+1</sub> = P(k+1), a<sub>k+2</sub> = P(k+2), …, a<sub>k+m</sub> = P(k+m)*. These are the results.

#### Output

If the code is a function, return an array [*a<sub>k+1</sub>, a<sub>k+2</sub>, …, a<sub>k+m</sub>*].

If the code is a full program, print those numbers to stdout, separated by an any character you want.

Comment: I think you should require _some_ separator for the output: `1 4 9 16 25` is much less ambiguous than `1491625`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen OK then.

Comment: NB This is almost a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/implement-shamirs-secret-sharing-reconstruction . The differences are that it's over a field of characteristic 0; that the x-coords are implicit; and that it asks for extrapolation to *k+1*, ... *k+m* rather than to 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Golfscript, <strike>46 42 40</strike> 38 chars

```
~])\({[{.@-\}*])\}*;]-1%){0\{+.}/p]}*;
```

This uses a simple difference table approach, which is described in more [detail](http://www.cheddarmonk.org/golfscriptblog/2011/12/code-dissection-polynomial-extrapolation.html) on my GolfScript blog.

Comment: +100: You beat Ilmari's 40 char-or-less challenge :)

Comment: Bounty awarded. Congratulations! Now I just need to learn enough GolfScript to be able to understand your code. :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, I might write it up for my GolfScript blog in a few days. The `-2%` is quite interesting in that it's something I didn't really see much point to before.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, [code dissection](http://www.cheddarmonk.org/golfscriptblog/2011/12/code-dissection-polynomial-extrapolation.html) posted to my blog.

Answer (score 4):

### Maple, 41 chars

```
c:=(k,a,m)->interp([$1-k..0],a,x)$x=1..m;
```

For example, `c(3, [1, 2, 4], 4)` returns `7, 11, 16, 22`.

This function interprets the spec literally, taking both `k` and `a` as separate arguments.  If the list `a` does not have exactly `k` elements, an error occurs.  For convenience, here's a 45-char version that omits `k` from the argument list:

```
c:=(a,m)->interp([$1-nops(a)..0],a,x)$x=1..m;
```

I was first thinking of trying this in Perl, but hell, let's use the right tool for the job.

Comment: BTW, since this is code golf, 'the right tool' is golfscript. :P

Comment: @JiminP: OK, challenge accepted. The first person to solve this task in 40 or fewer chars in GolfScript gets a 100 rep bounty from me.

Comment: @PeterTaylor When inputs are integers, outputs might always be integers (there's a way to calculate outputs by using only integers), even though I don't have any proofs.

Comment: Challenge met. Don't feel obliged to give me the bounty, though; I'm doing ok for rep already.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I'll give it to you anyway, it's not like I'm starved for rep either.  And I did promise.  (I assume I have to wait until the question is old enough, though, since I don't see any "start a bounty" link yet.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes, language postdates challenge

```
Iß;@Ḣ+\øṁ⁹µL?
çUḣU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASsA1P//ScOfO0DhuKIrXMO44bmB4oG5wrVMPwrDp1XhuKNV////WzEsMiw0Xf80)

Jelly's functions only support up to two arguments, so I don't take in *k* (which is redundant) as an argument. I hope that's acceptable. The program defines a function `2ŀ` that obeys the specification in the question.

### Explanation

**Helper function** `1ŀ` (takes input λ, ρ, and expands λ by ρ elements):

```
Iß;@Ḣ+\øṁ⁹µL?
       ø  µ ? If
           L    {λ} is nonempty,
              then:
I               take differences of consecutive elements of {λ};
 ß              call 1ŀ recursively on this value and {ρ};
  ;@            prepend
    Ḣ           the first element of {λ};
     +\         and take the cumulative sum {and return it}.
              Otherwise:
        ṁ⁹      {return} {0} repeated ρ times.
```

This is fairly magical in the way in which Jelly happens to pick out the exactly values I need it to operate on at every stage. Some of it is the result of me manipulating things; in particular, the unusual choice `ø` for the separator (rather than the more usual `µ`) means that all implicit arguments are set to 0, which is fairly handy in this case. However, I have no idea why `;@Ḣ` parses the way it does, but it seems to work…

**Main function** `2ŀ` (takes input λ, ρ, and returns the next ρ elements of λ):

```
çUḣU
ç             Call 1ŀ on {λ} and {ρ};
 U            reverse it;
  ḣ           take the first {ρ} elements;
   U          and reverse it {and return that value}.
```

This is just massaging the output into the form requested (if we were allowed to return the terms we were already given, that would remove a whole 5 bytes). Jelly doesn't have a "last n elements" function; of the various ways to synthesize it out of other functions, `UḣU` is convenient here because it happens to pick up ρ as a default argument.

Answer (score 1):

#### Golfscript, 51 characters

Similar approach to Peter's one.

```
~])\-1%[{(.@{.@\-}%\;.,}do;]-1%\[0]\*\{\{+.}%\;}%;p
```

When run on input

```
2 3 12 35 78
4
```

it yields the result

```
[147 248 387 570]
```

There are still possible places where the solution might be golfable further.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 128 bytes

```scala
m=>Stream.iterate(_)(a=>a.tail.lazyZip(a)map(_-_)).takeWhile(Nil!=).:\(Seq.fill(m)(0))((a,b)=>b.scanLeft(a(0))(_+_))takeRight(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/O7mS7rrXSMCrvzTttt4L8w)