# Nth Differences

Tags: code-golf, math, array

In math, one way to figure out what the type of a given relation (linear, quadratic, etc) is to calculate the differences.  To do so you take a list of y values for which the gap between the correspondent x values is the same, and subtract each one from the number above it, creating a list of numbers one shorter then the previous list.  If the resultant list is completely composed of identical numbers, then the relation has a difference of 1 (it is linear).  If they are not identical, then you repeat the process on the new list.  If they are now identical, the relation has a difference of 2 (it is quadratic).  If they are not identical, you simply continue this process until they are.  For example, if you have the list of y values `[1,6,15,28,45,66]` for incrementally increasing x values:

```
First Differences:

1
6   1-6  =-5
15  6-15 =-9
28  15-28=-13
45  28-45=-17
66  45-66=-21

Second differences:

-5 
-9  -5+9  =4
-13 -9+13 =4
-17 -13+17=4
-21 -17+21=4

As these results are identical, this relation has a difference of 2
```

### Your Task

Write a program or function that, when given an array of integers as input, returns the difference of the relation described by the array, as explained above.

### Input

An array of integers, which may be of any length>1.

### Output

An integer representing the difference of the relation described by the input.

### Test Cases

```
Input                            => Output
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]           => 1
[1,4,9,16,25,36]                 => 2
[1,2,1]                          => 2 (when there is only one value left, all values are automatically identical, so the largest difference an array can have is equal to the length of the array-1)
"Hello World"                    => undefined behavior (invalid input)
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]              => 0 (all elements are already identical)
[1, 3, 9, 26, 66, 150, 313, 610] => 6
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes in each language wins for that language.  Lowest score overall gets the green checkmark.

Comment: Can the input be "invalid" as in, if the input is to NOT conform to the provided spec, should we error? Provide -1 as the output?

Comment: Behavior is undefined for invalid input (I don't care what your code does)

Comment: Shouldn't `[1,2,1]` give 2? `[1,2,1] -> [1,-1] -> [-2]`

Comment: @HyperNeutrino, yep, sorry.  I had a brain-fart there

Comment: Add this test case `[1,3,9,26,66,150,313,610]` -> `6` if you like

Comment: Related, potential dupe targets: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/q/4229/194 , https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47005/194 , https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65409/194 , https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/119301/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor the third one you suggested is really similar, so I don't know if this counts as a good question.

Comment: The description talks about an array with any number of integers, but all the test cases are arrays of at least 2 positive integers. Do solutions need to handle 0s, negative numbers, empty arrays, and arrays of a single element?

Comment: @PatrickStephansen, yes, yes, no, and yes.

Answer (score 10):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

Thanks [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393/leo) for letting me use his version that works for `[1,1,1,1,1,1]`

```
←VE¡Ẋ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbhDDXQwsf7urS/f//f7ShjomOpY6hmY6RqY6xWSwA)

#### Explanation

```
   ¡     Repeatedly apply function, collecting results in a list
    Ẋ-     Differences
 VE      Get the index of the first place in the list where all the elements are equal
←        Decrement
```

Comment: Whenever someone said Husk is the new Jelly, they were pretty dang right. >_<

Comment: Damn, I was gonna post [this](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbhDDXQwsf7urS/f//f7ShjomOpY6hmY6RqY6xWSwA). Good job though, +1!

Comment: @Leo, test case I didn't see `[1,1,1,1]`, can I use yours?

Comment: @H.PWiz sure, go on!

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

```js
f=a=>-a.every(x=>i=!x)||1+f(a.map(n=>n-a[++i]))
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=a=>-a.every(x=>i=!x)||1+f(a.map(n=>n-a[++i]))

console.log(f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))    // 1
console.log(f([1,4,9,16,25,36]))          // 2
console.log(f([1,2,1]))                   // 2
console.log(f([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]))       // 0
console.log(f([1,3,9,26,66,150,313,610])) // 6
```

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
`dta}x@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyGlJLG2wqHw//9oQx0THUsdQzMdI1MdY7NYAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D8hpSSxtsKh8H@sS8j/aEMdIx1jHRMdUx0zHXMdCx1LHUODWC6gsAmIaaZjZKpjbAYWMNIxBNNoECymYKyjYKmjYGSmo2AGxIamBkAhQ6CgGdA0AA).

#### Explanation

This compuntes consecutive differences iteratively until the result is all zeros or empty. The output is the required number of iterations minus 1.

```
`      % Do... while
  d    %   Consecutive diffferences. Takes input (implicitly) the first time
  t    %   Duplicate
  a    %   True if any element is nonzero. This is the loop condition
}      % Finally (execute before exiting the loop)
  x    %   Delete. This removes the array of all zeros
  @    %   Push iteration index
  q    %   Subtract 1. Implicitly display
       % End (implicit). Proceed with next iteration if top of the stack is true
```

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>50</s> 44 bytes

```r
function(l){while(any(l<-diff(l)))F=F+1
F*1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9PI0ezujwjMydVIzGvUiPHRjclMy0NKKip6Wbrpm3I5Vb7P00jWcNQx9BMx8hCx8RUx8xMU/M/AA)

Takes a `diff` of `l`, sets it to `l`, and checks if the result contains any nonzero values. If it does, increment `F` (initialized as `FALSE` implicitly), and returns `F*1` to convert `FALSE` to `0` in the event that all of `l` is identical already.

Comment: [Full program and `+F` trick for 5 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/pvqGBopmBkoWBiqmBm9j/Htjg5MU9D07o8IzMnVSMxr1Ijx0Y3JTMtTSNHU1PTzdZN29Ba2w1NFwA). Neat answer btw!

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
(s=#;t=0;While[!SameQ@@s,s=Differences@s;t++];t)&
```

*thanx @alephalpa for -6 bytes and @hftf -1 byte*

and here is another approach from @hftf

## Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
Length@NestWhileList[Differences,#,!SameQ@@#&]-1&
```

Comment: `(s=#;t=0;While[UnsameQ@@s,s=Differences@s;t++];t)&`

Comment: `UnsameQ[1,2,1]` is False; `!SameQ[1,2,1]` is True. I don't think the manual loop saves characters either: `Length@NestWhileList[Differences,#,!SameQ@@#&]-1&` is already the same length as yours after replacing `UnsameQ` with `!SameQ`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 37 bytes

```perl6
{($_,{@(.[] Z- .[1..*])}...*.none)-2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BCsIwEEX3nmLALhL5DZ2kGSul4jksRVzUlVbRlZSePaabEkSZxcD8N5/36J9XCbc3ZRdqwqiyE8aDMm1Hx5xMy8ZsOj2ZuMxwH3qd2ynUq9d5flCKIWAPW6H0ENG6pjU1e7IJYeFQIsbYosIOXCwYJ1g5RwLr4f718M/71yxMkTAulluJhtG2gGMHSTQkfAA)

**Explanation:** The function takes the input as one list. It then builds a recursive sequence like this: the first element is the original list (`$_`), the next elements are returned by `{@(@$_ Z- .[1..*])}` being called on the previous element, and that is iterated until the condition `*.none` is true, which happens only when the list is either empty or contains only zeroes (or, technically, other falsey values). We then grab the list and subtract 2 from it, which forces it first to the numerical context (and lists in numerical context are equal to the number of their elements) and, at the end, returns 2 less than the number of elements in the list.

The weird block `{@(@$_ Z- .[1..*])}` just takes the given list (`.[]` — so called *Zen slice* — indexing with empty brackets yields the whole list), zips it using the minus operator (`Z-`) with the same list without the first element (`.[1..*]`) and forces it to a list (`@(...)` — we need that because zip returns only a Seq, which is basically an one-way list that can be iterated only once. Which is something we don't like.) And that's it.

Comment: Changing `@(.[] Z- .[1..*])` to `[.[] Z-.[1..*]]` should save two bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
-Iß$E?‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/X8/B8FVf7Rw0z/v//H22oo2Cso2Cpo2BkpqNgBsSGpgZAIUOgoJmhQSwA)

### Explanation

```
-Iß$E?‘  Input: array A
     ?   If
    E    All elements are equal
         Then
-          Constant -1
         Else
   $       Monadic chain
 I           Increments
  ß          Recurse
      ‘  Increment
```

Comment: Non-recursive alternative: `IÐĿE€ċ0`

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

```
è@=ä-)d
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=6EA95C0pZA==&input=WzEsIDMsIDksIDI2LCA2NiwgMTUwLCAzMTMsIDYxMF0=)

Relies on the fact that the result is guaranteed to be within the length of the input array.

### Explanation

```
è@=ä-)d     Implcit input of array U
 @          For each value in U...
  =ä-)      Update U to be equal to its subsections, each reduced by subtraction
      d     Check if any values in that are truthy
è           Count how many items in that mapping are true
```

By the end, this will map the array
`[1, 3, 9, 26, 66, 150, 313, 610]` to `[true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false]`,
which contains `6` `true`s.

### Previous 10 byte version

```
@=ä-)e¥0}a
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QD3kLSllpTB9YQ==&input=WzEsIDMsIDksIDI2LCA2NiwgMTUwLCAzMTMsIDYxMF0=)

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>191 + 58 = 249</s> <s>198</s> 140 bytes.

Thanks PunPun1000 for 51 bytes.
Thanks Nevay for 58 bytes.

```java
int f(int[]a){int x=a.length-1,b[]=new int[x];for(;x-->0;)b[x]=a[x+1]-a[x];return java.util.Arrays.stream(a).distinct().count()<2?0:1+f(b);}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##jY/PboMwDMbP61PkmKgmItBmf1g37QF26hFxMBS6MAhVEjoqxLN3QVsvPSFLtmx/n/xzjWcMulOp68P39dTnjSpI0aC15BOVHlfWoVPFVWlHKupzmiEb527YIW9KfXRfgYA8zXa6/CGzYMiSqjM0GYLgLUxY7gc7TIe1yAKcl6Z0vdGk9od571TDP4zBi@XWmRJbiowflHVKF44yXnS99vU1eg9fxLqiOUumG@YfGjl36kBaD0v3zih9TDOC5mjZuHrYX6wrW971jp/8yjWaVvTGmZFRQAQxbGALEh7hCZ5BhBNjyRLnZlZLiLYQy6WeCMRS6V0stcWeKpIgJYhtCLGIQf6/NE3XXw)

[Try it Online (198 byte version)](https://tio.run/##jY8xb4MwEIXn5ld4tMXFwpC4rVwPHTt0yhgxGGJSE2IibFIixG9PTZqoUidk6fmke9/pvUqd1bI5aVvtDtdTl9emQEWtnEOfythh4bzyprga61GJg24zRYYqQLTzpqbOt1od6Yf1m9uEDvJv@d626uLuHqyImK5UUtFa273/WjJxO5hLq7/RNFaZMCU@0J1x3tjCY0KLprPhl5KRVvuutSgWunYalU075UG9jEX/Vok@iki@7TOpgiyDRCwTd4RFJc6JGB8Ff0uhc2N26Bhq4hDe2P02Q6rdOzIsnjYX5/WRNp2np7DytcUlfsTM0MAggRRWsAYOz/ACr8DikRAxh1xNbg7JGlI@l0mAzbX@e3OxNKRKOHAObB1DylLg90rjeP0B)

So, this is my first time posting here in PPCG (and the first time ever doing a code golf challenge). Any constructive criticism is welcome and appreciated. I tried to follow the guidelines for posting, if anything's not right feel free to point it out.

Beautified version:

```java
int f(int[] a) {
    int x = a.length - 1, b[] = new int[x];
    for (; x-- > 0;) {
        b[x] = a[x + 1] - a[x];
    }
    return java.util.Arrays.stream(a).distinct().count() < 2 ? 0 : 1 + f(b);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Instead of importing those modules you can just use `java.util.stream.IntStream k = java.util.Arrays.stream(a);`

Comment: In fact, there are a couple of changes you can make for free.  1) `public` doesn't need to be included in the byte count.  2) You should not be accepting a second parameter, but removing it can actually save bytes. 3) you can remove some unneeded brackets there

Comment: 4) Not a saver but you should include a TIO if possible, here is an example with those suggestions at 198 bytes [TIO](https://tio.run/##jY8xb4MwEIXn5ld4tMXFwpC4rVwPHTt0yhgxGGJSE2IibFIixG9PTZqoUidk6fmke9/pvUqd1bI5aVvtDtdTl9emQEWtnEOfythh4bzyprga61GJg24zRYYqQLTzpqbOt1od6Yf1m9uEDvJv@d626uLuHqyImK5UUtFa273/WjJxO5hLq7/RNFaZMCU@0J1x3tjCY0KLprPhl5KRVvuutSgWunYalU075UG9jEX/Vok@iki@7TOpgiyDRCwTd4RFJc6JGB8Ff0uhc2N26Bhq4hDe2P02Q6rdOzIsnjYX5/WRNp2np7DytcUlfsTM0MAggRRWsAYOz/ACr8DikRAxh1xNbg7JGlI@l0mAzbX@e3OxNKRKOHAObB1DylLg90rjeP0B)

Comment: Also you might want to check out these tips pages for [Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) and [All languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) to help you get familiar with the more common golfing tricks.  Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @PunPun1000 thanks for the input! The second parameter is meant to count the number of times the recursion was called (which is conveniently also the difference of the relation), is that wrong? I don't know how I could do it without that parameter. Also, I'll try to golf it down further with the tips you gave me, thanks again!

Comment: @J.Salle if you checked the TIO I linked above it shows how to avoid the second variable

Comment: @PunPun1000 yeah I just checked it. I'm not very good at this yet hahahah. I'll edit the post in a couple minutes, thanks for the tips!

Comment: [140 bytes](https://tio.run/##jY/PboMwDMbP61PkmKgmItBmf1g37QF26hFxMBS6MAhVEjoqxLN3QVsvPSFLtmx/n/xzjWcMulOp68P39dTnjSpI0aC15BOVHlfWoVPFVWlHKupzmiEb527YIW9KfXRfgYA8zXa6/CGzYMiSqjM0GYLgLUxY7gc7TIe1yAKcl6Z0vdGk9od571TDP4zBi@XWmRJbiowflHVKF44yXnS99vU1eg9fxLqiOUumG@YfGjl36kBaD0v3zih9TDOC5mjZuHrYX6wrW971jp/8yjWaVvTGmZFRQAQxbGALEh7hCZ5BhBNjyRLnZlZLiLYQy6WeCMRS6V0stcWeKpIgJYhtCLGIQf6/NE3XXw "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Nevay I'd never seen the `x-->0` syntax before. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I just noticed it's actually the loop condition, didn't see the first `;` there.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>22</s> 17 bytes

```apl
{1=≢∪⍵:0⋄1+∇2-/⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/2tD2UeeiRx2rHvVutTJ41N1iqP2oo91IVx/Ir/3v9qhtAl4VXI/6pgLVuCk86t1saPAfAA)

Thanks to @ngn for -5 bytes!

### How?

- `{ ... }`, the function
- `1=≢∪⍵:0`, if every element is equal in the argument, return `0`
- `1+∇2-/⍵`, otherwise, return 1 + `n` of the differences (which is `n-1`, thus adding one to it gives `n`)

Comment: it's shorter if you sacrifice tail-recursiveness: `{1=≢∪⍵:0⋄1+∇2-/⍵}`

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 46 bytes

```
g l|all(==l!!0)l=0|0<1=1+g(zipWith(-)l$tail l)
```

this simply recurses - `zipWith(-)l$last l` is the difference list of `l`. and `g` is the function that answers the question.

Comment: the recursive solution was the good one.

Comment: @jferard that's very true

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>98</s> 94 bytes

```java
a->{int o=0,i,z=1;for(;z!=0;o++)for(i=a.length-1,z=0;i>o;a[i]-=a[--i])z|=a[o]^a[i];return~-o;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZAxT8MwEIX3/opjS1TbjVMIIJNKLEgMTGWLgmTatLi4dpQ4RW0Jfz2cS6iQYKo4efCd7c/vvZXcSGrLwqzmr13ZPGs1g5mWdQ0PUhnYDwaAVTvp8GChjNSwwiescUqzRWNmTlnDHu29cXd9d6OMy/IJGEg7SSd7bMGmEVFkl3KxsFUgdmdpJOxwGPpOpZLpwizdC@V4JRJqYoXMVE5TmVGq8nD3jjubP/mhqArXVOaDWtF2Xpv4kthr75VurJrDGh0EU1cps8xykNWyDtEQ9DXd1q5YM9s4VuIVp01gmCxLvb2t0U1gijc4OIE9JxATGBM4J3BBICFwSeCKwDUBHrVhKDxvNAJ@IhyBHLkxIs89P/lmHgvh8enK@S/ef8H/Xj@/Q3h0Inx8SDhOfCI@oQhHHIfJMXSEJwd4O2i7Tw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 77 bytes

first post, tried to edit last answer on kotlin 2 times ;D

```kotlin
{var z=it;while(z.any{it!=z[0]})z=z.zip(z.drop(1),{a,b->a-b});it.size-z.size}
```

took testing part from @jrtapsell

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##hVHBauMwEL3nK6ZhDxJMTJw03jatA4VmoVDYw/a27EFN5FZUkY006RIbf3t2JLdh2UN2jJH85r2Z8Zu3mqxxx3flwS3Fowl0@@BoJScrPqA8djHTloZufr8aq0WbKXfoDF2U7c/pr162ZZu1pmF86@tG5BI7hc@TlZo89/LGUBZMqydtOvrjVpGCjVUhwJMOdM@fIjYwrtnTEk7tESJa7ynBjMjRqNo72CnjhPIvYQl33qvD7Q/yxr2sJHQj4HhXFgzpXYASLBf7XomExzg1/EjkOMM5XuICC/yKV3iN@VQi8B@ckVxGWoGzBc4LJs/OkmeY/5fzz8P86Vk@zBGuuWiBUPCbL6YM5QwWafpCJi3b9WlHpYyNdiRbsp1qoOM7UA1O8HqS8xL6rDKWtE9JvvtA2WA/XERtFvSmdlvoh8KmApEKZyasdw0dhPxcQYyGl0LWiXGcHxpet96Oh8l60Dbov7hDmar2a7V5he4k/Xb38Li@X8IXQ2PZD9pRf/wD)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first answer, an outgolf too.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
IÐĿEÐḟL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z8IQj@10PT3i4Y77P////ow11LHSMzHXMTHQMjUxjAQ)

## Explanation

```
IÐĿEÐḟL  Main link
 ÐĿ      While results are unique (which is never so it stops at [])
I        Take the increments, collecting intermediate values # this computes all n-th differences
    Ðḟ   Filter out
   E     Lists that have all values equal (the first n-th difference list that is all equal will be removed and all difference lists after will be all 0s)
      L  Take the length (this is the number of iterations required before the differences become equal)
```

-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan

Comment: @Gryphon Done! :)

Comment: `IÐĿEÐḟL` for seven (I see Miles also found a seven using recursion).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Cool thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 58 bytes

```
f=a=>+(b=a.slice(1).map((e,i)=>e-a[i])).some(e=>e)&&1+f(b)
```

Comment: +0, not enough Jquery :p. Really though, +1, nice job, I know I would never be able to golf in JS.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan.*

```python
f=lambda l,c=1:any(l)and f([j-i for i,j in zip(l,l[1:])],c-1)or-c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsMgEEDRq8xSYYRMSoUGcpLgwhqkE6ajSDbJ5a1d/M3j1@v8FJ17z6vE73uPIJhWWqJeRmzUHbLZDseQSwPGA1jh5moEZaMl2IDJkS3NpV4b6/nfCeGB8EKYPYIf0XMaRAM9TcH2Hw)

Comment: Save a byte initialising `c` to `1`, decrementing and then using `print-c`.

Comment: Save six more by making it into a recursive function: [`f=lambda l,c=1:any(l)and f([j-i for i,j in zip(l,l[1:])],c-1)or-c`](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsMgEEDRq8xSYYRMSoUGcpLgwhqkE6ajSDbJ5a1d/M3j1@v8FJ17z6vE73uPIJhWWqJeRmzUHbLZDseQSwPGA1jh5moEZaMl2IDJkS3NpV4b6/nfCeGB8EKYPYIf0XMaRAM9TcH2Hw)

Comment: Is it just me or is the switch to a recursive lambda not saving enough bytes? :P Thanks!

Comment: I think this needs a `max(...,0)` to pass the `[1, 1, 1, 1, ...]` test cases.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
[DË#¥]N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/2uVwt/KhpbF@QKahjoKxjoKljoKRmY6CGRAbmhoAhQyBgmaGBrEA)

**Explanation**

```
[         # start loop
 D        # duplicate current list
  Ë       # are all elements equal?
   #      # if so, break
    ¥     # calculate delta's
     ]    # end loop
      N   # push iteration counter
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>66</s> <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```hs
z=(=<<tail).zipWith
f=length.takeWhile(or.z(/=)).iterate(z(-))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/LCoMwEEXX9SsG6SKBMTU@0gpm3z9wUVwETGswVbFZ5edt2k0h5TKbM2cY7qhek7Z2370ksm2dMpYyb9bOuDG5S6vnhxuZU5PuRmM1WTbmyUlSyozTm3KaeJJRuj@VmUHCsEByWDczOzjCHW4cCyyxwhoFnvGCDfK8j4zqQwUWNZai/7vmMYoSr6FEaBAKgSDC8DoPiAcovp@zDH56eg3VF@iWzQ7p/gY)

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to Christian Sievers*

*Saved 1 byte thanks to proud-haskeller*

`iterate(z(-))` computes the differences lists.

`or.z(/=)` tests if there are non equal elements in those lists.

`length.takeWhile` counts the differences lists with non equal elements.

Comment: I think you can test for non-equal elements with `or.z(/=)`

Comment: @ChristianSievers thanks! That was obvious, but I didn't see it...

Comment: You can also use `z=(=<<tail).zipWith`, one byte shorter

Comment: @proudhaskeller and more elegant, as always with point free definitions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 19 bytes

```
≢-1+(≢2-/⍣{1=≢∪⍵}⊢)
```

Explanation:

```
≢                      length of input
 -1+(             )    minus 1+
     ≢                 length of
      2-/              differences between elements
         ⍣             while
          {1=≢∪⍵}      there is more than 1 unique element
                 ⊢     starting with the input
```

Comment: Does this work? `≢-1+∘≢2-/⍣{1=≢∪⍵}⊢`

Answer (score 2):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), 21 bytes

```
#1_(~&/1_=':)(1_-':)\
```

This works in k, but not in oK, because oK's while loop runs before checking the condition (as opposed to first checking the condition, and then running the code). Therefore, in oK, the `1 1 1 1 1` example will not work properly.

[Try oK online!](https://tio.run/##LYlLCoAwEEOvMiBohYhNa8dP8SZCd9248AZevc5CQj683NNzt1aPjsW9/cxyDsfoWCarq9XBEQERCxIUKzbsoM80YEMREqJmShBa/rJbImSHBIWomckbokGlH9sH)

[image: Running the k example with 1 1 1 1 1 1 in the k interpreter.]

Explanation:

```
   (        )       \ /while(
    ~&/               /      not(min(
       1_=':          /              check equality of all pairs))) {
             (1_-':)  /    generate difference list
                      /    append to output }
#1_                   /(length of output) - 1
```

Comment: `~&/1_=':` -> `1<#?`

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 7 bytes

Same approach (but independently derived) as [Justin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142473/58974) with a different implementation.

```
£=äaÃèx
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=oz3kYcPoeA==&input=WzEsNiwxNSwyOCw0NSw2Nl0=)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of array `U`.

```
£   Ã
```

Map over each element.

```
äa
```

Take each sequential pair (`ä`) of elements in `U` and reduce it by absolute difference (`a`).

```
=
```

Reassign that array to `U`.

```
èx
```

Count (`è`) the number of sub-arrays that return truthy (i.e., non-zero) when reduced by addition.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 19 bytes

```
While max(abs(ΔList(Ans
ΔList(Ans
IS>(A,9
End
A
```

By default, variables start at zero. Also, never thought I'd be using `IS>(` for anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 15 bytes

```
W.E.+Q=.+Q=hZ)Z
```

**[Verify all the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=W.E.%2BQ%3D.%2BQ%3DhZ%29Z&input=%5B1%2C6%2C15%2C28%2C45%2C66%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C4%2C9%2C16%2C25%2C36%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+3%2C+9%2C+26%2C+66%2C+150%2C+313%2C+610%5D&debug=0)**

## How?

#### Explanation #1

```
W.E.+Q=hZ=.+Q)Z   ~ Full program.

W                 ~ While...
 .E.+Q            ~ ... The deltas of Q contain a truthy element.
      =hZ         ~ Increment a variable Z, which has the initial value of 0.
         =        ~ Transform the variable to the result of a function applied to itself...
          .+Q     ~ ... Operate on the current list and deltas.
             )Z   ~ Close the loop and output Z.
```

Comment: -1 byte `Wtl{Q=hZ=.+Q)Z`

Comment: @Dave Even better: `WP{Q=hZ=.+Q)Z`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>70</s> 69 + 18 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)*

```cs
g=a=>i=>a.Distinct().Count()>1?g(a.Zip(a.Skip(1),(y,z)=>y-z))(i+1):i;
```

Must be given 0 when calling to operate correctly. Also included in byte count:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLTsMwEDw3X2FOtcU2ihsaHm2CUHkICSRED0jcjGuFFa4TYgf6UL89OI1aBGtpZz2zlmdX2oEsKtXUFk1OZivr1CJ8QPM5DoxYKFsKqfb0tNBaSYeFseGdMqpCGWwC4kNqYS252tUd04Z1wqEkXwXOyaNAQ9lB2gS9Fm5rIyf3N6ZeqEq8aTVB4zLoaF8Cae8ZyUlKTK31uMlTkWaYZiK8RuvQSEeZ91Ubjxm/zKkIX7H0efbhgTOgKyBrlmarwZoxisecXeC4OfjobFbt7GjK2o3/KN/vqBWhdCd5D1M/eaFV@KzE3O9IUcbIUWeNBb3eXn6p0KmdnndPw1mp0dE@9Fk4U@0O6ZKkWTtd@CQqq@iSeXcRY7//b4MubxsOQ4jhBEaQwCmcwTnwKOCe8EUCwxHESdD2cJ//Hc/Evm2YQJIAH0UQ8xgSHv0A)

Explanation:

```cs
g = a => i =>                      // Function taking two arguments (collection of ints and an int)
    a.Distinct()                   // Filter to unique elements
    .Count() > 1 ?                 // If there's more than one element
        g(                         //     Then recursively call the function with
            a.Zip(                 //     Take the collection and perform an action on corresponding elements with another one
                a.Skip(1),         //         Take our collection starting at second element
                (y, z) => y - z    //         Perform the subtraction
            )
        )(i + 1)                   //     With added counter
        : i;                       // Otherwise return counter
```

Iterative version 84 + 18 bytes:

```cs
a=>{int i=0;for(;a.Distinct().Count()>1;i++)a=a.Zip(a.Skip(1),(y,z)=>y-z);return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBNSwMxEL3vrxhPTXAb7DnNgtQPBAVxD4K3mE51MM2u@dB@0N@@Ji219B1mknkv4c0zYWw6j0MK5D6gXYeIS/FI7ltWTi8x9NrgcTzrrEUTqXNB3KNDT6baVpBhrA4Brvfnw6QgRB3JwE9Hc3jS5Bj/p06igrvkzPTh1qUlev1ucUouNjWUCgtQg1bNNl@A1JVcdJ5JLW4oRHImMp5tJZd7M5F0ecm10uKNeqZF@5XbhNdsXW@4atbjDZceY/IOSO4GWZ15CNGXBMj1Kcoz5veTLAJjewoUzPL@nUXxgnqek0LGOVwocMlafvaw4Ch@9RRxr14cPhJtbymyUT3iosWSK1uBasrS4ln7gGzFM05WdtWh7oY/)

Comment: You can remove the redundant space at `(y,z)=>y-z`. But nice answer, +1 from me.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thank you! Also, oops.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 62 bytes

```
#(loop[c % i 0](if(apply = c)i(recur(map -(rest c)c)(inc i))))
```

Nicely `=` can take any number of arguments, and a single argument is identical to "itself". `(apply = [1 2 3])` gets executed as `(= 1 2 3)`.

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was trying to do but I was struggling for a compact pairwise diffs. That's brilliant, I'll have to remember that for the future.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
⁽¯İ~aL
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oG9wq/EsH5hTCIsIiIsIlsxLDIsMyw0LDUsNiw3LDgsOSwxMF1cblsxLDQsOSwxNiwyNSwzNl1cblsxLDIsMV1cblsxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMV1cblsxLCAzLCA5LCAyNiwgNjYsIDE1MCwgMzEzLCA2MTBdIl0=)

Explanation:

```
⁽¯      # Single element lambda that gets the differences
  İ     # Apply that and collect results until no change
   ~    # Filter by:
    a   #   Any truthy?
     L  # Get the length of those
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>21</sup> 18 bytes

```
2#@(}.~.)2-/\^:a:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzNCoJAEIDvPsWYgSuN286aCw4KUtApOnQ1@yGS6NIDRL36thr@MMxhv2@/edrMZ6qNz1kYejMZNlAwhICggN3GEjaH3dbqoBQf@ZWRjpfHE1@5tpG3X0uoOOfSyVi@ORKtraPWd1LQouI5/@lFcSkFFUHpzkzaIRKUd27Iz9rlLZre9e63xwsaIFxhhmRQp5iYgYIGGh/djAUkCBmCNgjGLaXKIXLQkOp/qX7sDw)

*-3 thanks to rdm!*

Comment: 2#@(}.~.)2-/\^:a:]

Comment: Very nice again!

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 83 + 1 (-a) = 84 bytes

```perl
sub c{$r=0;$r||=$_-$F[0]for@F;$r}for(;c;$i=0){$_-=$F[++$i]for@F;$#F--}say y/ //-$#F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhuVqlyNbAWqWopsZWJV5XxS3aIDYtv8jBDShUC2RoWCdbq2TaGmhWA2VtgdLa2iqZMBXKbrq6tcWJlQqV@gr6@rpA/v//hgomCpYKhmb/8gtKMvPziv/r@prqGRga/NdNBAA)

Input as a list of numbers separated by one space.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 11 bytes

```
W$D}ltoK)Ko
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=W%24D%7DltoK%29Ko&input=%5B1%2C+3%2C+9%2C+26%2C+66%2C+150%2C+313%2C+610%5D&warnings=1&hex=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 83 bytes

```kotlin
{var z=it
var c=0
while(z.any{it!=z[0]}){c++
z=(0..z.size-2).map{z[it+1]-z[it]}}
c}
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
{
    // Make input mutable
    var z=it
    // Count for returning
    var c=0
    // While the array is not identical
    while (z.any { it != z[0] }) {
        // Increment count
        c++
        // Update list to differences
        z = (0..z.size-2).map { z[it+1] - z[it] }
    }
    // Return count
    c
}
```

### Test

```kotlin
var n:(List<Int>)->Int =
{var z=it
var c=0
while(z.any{it!=z[0]}){c++
z=(0..z.size-2).map{z[it+1]-z[it]}}
c}

data class TestData(var input: List<Int>, var output: Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val items = listOf(
        TestData(listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 1),
        TestData(listOf(1,4,9,16,25,36), 2),
        TestData(listOf(1,2,1), 2),
        TestData(listOf(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 0),
        TestData(listOf(1, 3, 9, 26, 66, 150, 313, 610), 6)
    )

    val fails = items.map { it to n(it.input) }.filter { it.first.output != it.second }

    if (fails.isEmpty()) {
        println("Test passed")
    } else {
        fails.forEach {println("FAILED: $it")}
    }
}
```

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##hVFRa9swEH73r7iGPUjkImyn8dZQBwrNoFDYw/ZW8iAcuRVTZGNdOmKj355J9hrGHrITRufvvvt0fPezIaPt@V12YNfsWTu6f7K04YtNuKA8D7HSl5qSmFRlmvx600axXkh7GjTdlP1LuvN8qObzpC9ZKkQvnO7VIufiINuhf9E0z3aLeO@8Typ/3kuSUBnpHPxQjh7DL4vq2rZHWsNlCISINkca4YDwJKmPFg5SWya7V7eGh66Tp/vv1Gn7uuEwJBDiXRrQpA4OSjBB7FvNRjzG5cE/hQxzXOItrrDAz/gF7zBLOULG8UrLbaQVmK9wWQRyfpWcY/Zfzj8n8NOrfFgi3AXRAqEIX7ZKA5QFsBinL/jYG@z6sKOW2kQ7RlviXmAIOVADlmkSo/McvKi1IdWNxZB3jsRkP9zEXuFU1dg9@ElY18BGYaHd9tDSifGPFcRow1LIWDaL80Mb1q32s2kyD8o49Rd3kqmbbiurNxgurV8fnp63j2v4pGnG/dSb@PNv)

Comment: If someone could edit to fix my language hints please, I can't seem to get them working

Comment: It's `lang-kotlin`, not simply `kotlin`, in the highlighter hints.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
tf!t{.+FQt
```

If we can index from 1, we can save a byte by removing the leading `t`.

[Try it Online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tf!t%7B.%2BFQt&input=[1%2C4%2C9%2C16%2C25%2C36]&debug=0)

Explanation

```
tf!t{.+FQt
 f        T  Find the first (1-indexed) value T...
     .+FQt   ... such that taking the difference T - 1 times...
  !t{        ... gives a set with more than one value in it.
t            0-index.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59c3094b6032437898077538), 90 bytes

```
func f(_ a:[Int])->Int{return a.contains{$0 != a[0]} ?f(zip(a, a.dropFirst()).map(-))+1:0}
```

Alternative, closure-based implementation:

```
var f: ((_ input: [Int]) -> Int)!
f = {a in a.contains{$0 != a[0]} ?f(zip(a, a.dropFirst()).map(-))+1:0}
```

[test cases:](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59c3094b6032437898077538)

```
let testcases: [(input: [Int], expected: Int)] = [
    (input: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],           expected: 1),
    (input: [1,4,9,16,25,36],                 expected: 2),
    (input: [1,2,1],                          expected: 2),
    (input: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],              expected: 0),
    (input: [1, 3, 9, 26, 66, 150, 313, 610], expected: 6),
]

for (caseNumber, testcase) in testcases.enumerated() {
    let actual = f(testcase.input)
    assert(actual == testcase.expected,
        "Testcase #\(caseNumber) \(testcase.input) failed. Got \(actual), but expected \(testcase.expected)!")
    print("Testcase #\(caseNumber) passed!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 58 bytes

```factor
[ 0 swap [ tuck all-eq? ] [ 1 + swap differences ] until ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9Pa8MwDMXv@RSPXstKHDfev8OO3S67jLFDycG4cmvqOqktM0bpZ8@8BroxCQn0fjwJWW24j@P728vr6gF7ioE80i5b6wnb2OfBhS0OmneXtkis2SV2JmGIxPw1RBcYiY6ZgqGEx6o6VShxgkADiSVaKNziDvcQNc5XuPwRFJoWUv2Rm1LTNHsm73t89NFvZlf@P3@dsixsFJSCaGtIIaEuB8/VuEaN9KkHrMHZ7KG9v6HjE7oiCMwntnHWUpze6JADO49uPBSygPGk4/gN)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```ruby
F=->a,i=0{a.uniq[1]?F[a.each_cons(2).map{_2-_1},i+1]:i}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN83dbHXtEnUybQ2qE_VK8zILow1j7d2iE_VSE5Mz4pPz84o1jDT1chMLquONdOMNa3UytQ1jrTJrodqtCxTcoqMNdUx0LHUMzXSMTHWMzWJjuaCiCsY6CpY6CkZmOgpmQGxoagAUMgQKmhkaxMZCjIC5BAA)