# Shamir's Secret Sharing

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, random, cryptography, polynomials

Given `n` (the number of players), `t` (the threshold value), and `s` (the secret), output the `n` secrets generated by [Shamir's Secret Sharing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing).

### The Algorithm

For the purposes of this challenge, the computations will be done in **GF(251)** (the finite field of size `251`, otherwise known as the integers *mod 251*). Ordinarily, the field would be chosen such that its size is a prime much greater than `n`. To simplify the challenge, the field size will be constant. `251` has been chosen because it is the largest prime representable by an 8-bit unsigned integer.

1. Generate `t-1` random integers in the (inclusive) range `[0, 250]`. Label these *a<sub>1</sub>* through *a<sub>t-1</sub>*.
2. Construct a `t-1`th degree polynomial using `s` as the constant value and the random integers from step 1 as the coefficients of the powers of `x`: *f(x) = s + x*a<sub>1</sub> + x<sup>2</sup>*a<sub>2</sub> + ... + x<sup>t-1</sup>*a<sub>t-1</sub>*.
3. Output `(f(z) mod 251)` for each `z` in the (inclusive) range `[1, n]`.

### Reference Implementation

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import sys

# Shamir's Secret Sharing algorithm
# Input is taken on the command line, in the format "python shamir.py n t s"

n, t, s = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:4]]
if t > n:
    print("Error: t must be less than or equal to n")
    exit()
if n not in range(2, 251):
    print("Error: n must be a positive integer less than 251")
    exit()
if t not in range(2, 251):
    print("Error: t must be a positive integer less than 251")
    exit()
if s not in range(251):
    print("Error: s must be a non-negative integer less than 251")
    exit()
p = 251
a = [random.randrange(0, 251) for x in range(t-1)]

def f(x):
    return s + sum(c*x**(i+1) for i,c in enumerate(a))

# Outputting the polynomial is for explanatory purposes only, and should not be included
#  in the output for the challenge
print("f(x) = {0} + {1}".format(s, ' + '.join('{0}*x^{1}'.format(c, i+1) for i,c in enumerate(a))))
for z in range(1, n+1):
    print(f(z) % p)
```

### Verification

The following Stack Snippet can be used to verify outputs:

```js
var validate = function() {
  $('#nts-error').attr('hidden', parseInt($('#n').val()) >= parseInt($('#t').val()));
  $('#check').prop('disabled', parseInt($('#n').val()) < parseInt($('#t').val()));
};

// the following function is taken from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#JavaScript
var combinations = function(arr, k) {
  var i,
    subI,
    ret = [],
    sub,
    next;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (k === 1) {
      ret.push([arr[i]]);
    } else {
      sub = combinations(arr.slice(i + 1, arr.length), k - 1);
      for (subI = 0; subI < sub.length; subI++) {
        next = sub[subI];
        next.unshift(arr[i]);
        ret.push(next);
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
};

// The following code is taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing#Javascript_example with the modification that the prime is 251, not 257

var prime = 251;

/* Gives the decomposition of the gcd of a and b.  Returns [x,y,z] such that x = gcd(a,b) and y*a + z*b = x */
function gcdD(a, b) {
  if (b == 0) return [a, 1, 0];
  else {
    var n = Math.floor(a / b),
      c = a % b,
      r = gcdD(b, c);
    return [r[0], r[2], r[1] - r[2] * n];
  }
}

/* Gives the multiplicative inverse of k mod prime.  In other words (k * modInverse(k)) % prime = 1 for all prime > k >= 1  */
function modInverse(k) {
  k = k % prime;
  var r = (k < 0) ? -gcdD(prime, -k)[2] : gcdD(prime, k)[2];
  return (prime + r) % prime;
}

/* Join the shares into a number */
function join(shares) {
  var accum, count, formula, startposition, nextposition, value, numerator, denominator;
  for (formula = accum = 0; formula < shares.length; formula++) {
    /* Multiply the numerator across the top and denominators across the bottom to do Lagrange's interpolation
     * Result is x0(2), x1(4), x2(5) -> -4*-5 and (2-4=-2)(2-5=-3), etc for l0, l1, l2...
     */
    for (count = 0, numerator = denominator = 1; count < shares.length; count++) {
      if (formula == count) continue; // If not the same value
      startposition = shares[formula][0];
      nextposition = shares[count][0];
      numerator = (numerator * -nextposition) % prime;
      denominator = (denominator * (startposition - nextposition)) % prime;
    }
    value = shares[formula][1];
    accum = (prime + accum + (value * numerator * modInverse(denominator))) % prime;
  }
  return accum;
}

$('#check').click(
  function() {
    var good = true;
    var problem = [];
    var n = parseInt($('#n').val());
    var t = parseInt($('#t').val());
    var s = parseInt($('#s').val());
    combinations([...Array(n + 1).keys()].slice(1), t).forEach(
      function(xArr) {
        var xfArr = xArr.map(
          function(x) {
            return [x, parseInt($('#f' + x).val())];
          }
        );
        var L = join(xfArr);
        if (L !== s) {
          good = false;
          problem.push(xArr);
        }
      }
    );
    $('#valid').html(good ? "True" : ("False (problematic secret sets: {" + problem.map(
      function(elem) {
        return "[" + elem.join(', ') + "]";
      }) + "})"));
  }
);

$('#n').change(
  function() {
    var inputHTML = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= parseInt($('#n').val()); i++) {
      inputHTML += 'f(' + i + '): <input type="number" min="0" max="250" value="0" id="f' + i + '"><br>\r\n';
    }
    $('#inputs').html(inputHTML);
    validate();
  }
);

$('#t').change(
  function() {
    validate();
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
n:
<input type="number" min="2" max="250" value="6" id="n">t:
<input type="number" min="2" max="250" value="3" id="t">s:
<input type="number" min="0" max="250" value="230" id="s">
<br>
<div id="nts-error" hidden="true">t must be less than or equal to n!</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="inputs">
  f(1):
  <input type="number" min="0" max="250" value="35" id="f1">
  <br>f(2):
  <input type="number" min="0" max="250" value="95" id="f2">
  <br>f(3):
  <input type="number" min="0" max="250" value="159" id="f3">
  <br>f(4):
  <input type="number" min="0" max="250" value="227" id="f4">
  <br>f(5):
  <input type="number" min="0" max="250" value="48" id="f5">
  <br>f(6):
  <input type="number" min="0" max="250" value="124" id="f6">
</div>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="check" value="Verify">
<br>
<br>Valid:
<div id="valid"></div>
```

### Rules

- `s` will be a non-negative integer less than `251`, and `n` and `t` will be positive integers less than `251` and greater than `1`. Furthermore, you are guaranteed that the inputs are valid (meaning `t <= n`).
- Input and output can be in any reasonable, unambiguous, and consistent format.
- Random numbers are to be sampled from a uniform distribution - each possible value should have equal probability of being chosen.

Comment: Do we have to output `z` __and__ `f(z)`? If I print an array of `f(z)`s in order, `z` is implied by index. `[[1, 5], [2, 2], [3, 9], [4, 14]]` does not contain more information than `[5, 2, 9, 14]`.

Comment: [Challenge for doing the inverse](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1230/31625).

Comment: @orlp Fair point.

Comment: Any testcases ?

Comment: @LeakyNun Since this question is tagged [tag:random], I think the verification snippet is much more valuable than test cases that will vary for each run.

Comment: @Mego I can't get your Stack Snippet to work; it is throwing a syntax error.

Comment: @Mego Just a heads up that your snippet is outputting `false` for every input and output except the default one.

Comment: @R.Kap I've tested it with other values (`n = 6, t = 3, s = 42, [146, 210, 234, 218, 162, 66]`) and it works. Are you sure the problem isn't in your program?

Comment: @Mego Yeah, I am sure, because, for instance, the input `n=5, t=4, s=7` produces a valid output `[10,247,217,172,113]` based on the 3 integers `[221,242,42]` as confirmed by my program and [your program](https://repl.it/C9tm/0), but the snippet outputs `false` for it.

Comment: @Mego The same is true for the input `n=2 ,t=2, s=212` and the output `[64,167]` based on the integer chosen `[35]` again [confirmed by your program](https://repl.it/C9ts/1).

Comment: @R.Kap In your last example, the chosen integer is `103`. I agree that there is something funky going on with the verification snippet - I blame Javascript. I'll take a look at it and see if I can figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @Mego Yeah, `[35]` was I typo. I meant to say `[103]`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
251©xX€⁵0¦ḅÐ€%®
```

Expects **t**, **n**, and **s** as command-line arguments. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MjUxwql4WOKCrOKBtTDCpuG4hcOQ4oKsJcKu&input=&args=Mw+Ng+MjMw)

#### How it works

```
251©xX€⁵0¦ḅÐ€%®  Main link. Left argument: t. Right argument: n Third argument: s

251©             Yield 251 and copy it to the register.
    x            Repeat [251] t times.
     X€          Random choice each; pseudo-randomly choose t integers from
                 [1, ..., 251]. Since 251 = 0 (mod 251), this is equivalent to
                 choosing them from [0, ..., 250].
       ⁵0¦       Replace the last generated integer (index 0) with s (⁵).
          ḅÐ€    Interpret the resulting array as a base-k number, for each k in
                 [1, ..., n], and convert to integer.
              ®  Yield 251 from the register.
             %   Take the generated integers modulo 251.
```

Comment: Replacing the last integer is so elegant :)

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, <s>59</s> 56 bytes

```mathematica
Mod[Power~Array~{#2,#-1}.RandomInteger[250,#-1]+#3,251]&
```

Takes three arguments in the order *t*, *n*, and *s*. Constructs a  2d-array with *n* rows and *t*-1 columns. Each row vector *j*, numbered from 1 thru *n*, contains the powers of *j* thru *j*<sup>*t*-1</sup>. Then a vector of random integer coefficients in the range 0 thru 250 is created with *t*-1 values. That is matrix-multiplied with the 2d-array, and then *s* is added element-wise and taken module 251 to get the value of the polynomial at each of the *n* points.

Comment: Was just about to post a 79-byte answer, nice trick with `Sum`!

Comment: I've got a different approach, but it's currently two bytes longer. Maybe you have an idea how to shorten it: `Mod[x#+#2&~Fold~RandomInteger[250,#2-1]x+#3/.x->Range@#,251]&`

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
{,:)@({;251mr}%@+fb251f%}
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=3%20230%206%0A%7B%2C%3A)%40(%7B%3B251mr%7D%25%40%2Bfb251f%25%7D%0A~p&input=3%20230%206)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 24 bytes

```
J+EmOK251tEm%s.e*b^dkJKS
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%2BEmOK251tEm%25s.e%2ab%5EdkJKS&input=5%0A7%0A3&debug=0)

Input order: `n` `s` `t` separated by linefeed.

Comment: arrrrrgh, ninja'd cuz i went to get a cookie

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 181 bytes

```javascript
(n,t,s)=>{r=Array(t-1).fill(0).map($=>{return Math.random()*251});f=(x=>{p = 0;r.map((k,c)=>p+=k*Math.pow(x, c));return s+p});_=Array(t-1).fill(0);_.map((l,i)=>_[i]=f(i));return _;}
```

Ungolfed:

```javascript
(n, t, s) => {
    r = Array(t - 1).fill(0).map($ =>{return Math.random() * 251});
    f = (x => {
        p = 0;
        r.map((k, c) => p += k * Math.pow(x, c));
        return s + p
    });
    _ = Array(t - 1).fill(0);
    _.map((l, i) => _[i] = f(i));
    return _;
}
```

I don't know how to properly check it, but I do know that it was a pain to get JS to map across a new array since apparently `.map` skips undefined values. If anyone sees any ways to improve, or flaws, don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: 123 bytes: `(n,t,s,A=f=>Array(t-1).fill(0).map(f),r=A($=>Math.random()*251))=>
  A((l,i,_,p=0)=>(r.map((k,c)=>p+=k*Math.pow(i,c)),s+p))`

Comment: You're not using `n`, which seems wrong. Your code also seems to be assuming 1-based indexing. `[...Array()]` is slightly shorter than `fiil()`. Also, the last two lines can be reduced to `return _.map(f);`

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
251tliq3$Yrihi:ZQw\
```

Input order is `t`, `s`, `n`.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MjUxdGxpcTMkWXJpaGk6WlF3XA&input=MwoyMzAKNg)

#### Explanation

```
251t    % Push 251 twice
l       % Push 1
iq      % Take input t. Subtract 1
3$Yr    % Generate t-1 random integers in [1 2 ... 251]
ih      % Take input s. Concatenate with the random integers
i:      % Take input n. Generate range [1 2 ... n]
ZQ      % Evvaluate polynomial at those values
w       % Swap to move copy og 251 to the top of the stack
\       % Modulo. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>138</s> 134 bytes

```csharp
(n,t,s)=>new int[n+1].Select((_,x)=>(s+new int[t-1].Select(k=>new Random(e).Next(251)).Select((c,i)=>c*Math.Pow(x+1,i+1)).Sum())%251);
```

C# lambda where inputs are `int` and output is an `IEnumerable<double>`. You can try my code on [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1jRVwd).

I am not 100% sure about the validity of my algorithm, please comment if I misunderstood something.

4 bytes saved with @raggy's [trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70934/15214).

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 48 bytes

```
f(n,t,s)=(1:n).^(0:t-1)'*[s;rand(0:250,t-1)]%251
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZihuLHQscyk9KDE6bikuXigwOnQtMSknKltzO3JhbmQoMDoyNTAsdC0xKV0lMjUxCgpmKDYsMywyMzApIHw-IHByaW50bG4&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
251|(1+i.@{.)p.~{:0}251?@#~1&{
```

Takes a list with the values *n*, *t*, and *s*.

Saved 2 bytes by using the *replace at index 0* idea from @Dennis's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84788/6710).

### Explanation

```
251|(1+i.@{.)p.~{:0}251?@#~1&{  Input: [n t s]
                           1&{  Select at index 1 (t)
                    251  #~     Create that many copies of 251
                       ?@       Generate that many random integers in [0, 251)
                {:              Get the tail of the input (s)
                  0}            Replace the value at index 0 of the random integer list
                                with s to make a coefficient list of the polynomial
          {.                    Get the head of the input (n)
       i.@                      Make the range [0, n-1]
     1+                         Add 1 to each to get [1, n]
             p.~                Evaluate the polynomial at each value [1, n]
251|                            Take each value mod 251 and return
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 116 bytes

```
(n,t,s)=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>++i&&t.reduce((r,a)=>r*i+a)%251,t=[...Array(t)].map(_=>--t?Math.random()*251|0:s))
```

I'd like to think this is one of the rare cases where `reduce` beats `map`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 with [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), 103 bytes

```
from numpy import*
lambda n,t,s:[poly1d(append(random.randint(0,251,t-1),s))(i+1)%251for i in range(n)]
```

I can honestly say that I never expected to use NumPy for code golf...

An anonymous function that takes input via argument and returns a list.

**How it works**

```
from numpy import*         Import everything in the NumPy library
lambda n,t,s...            Function with input number of players n, threshold value t and
                           secret s
random.randint(0,251,t-1)  Generate a NumPy array R of t-1 random integers in [0,250]
append(...,s)              Append s to R
poly1d(...)                Generate a polynomial p of order t-1 with coefficients R and
                           constant term s
...for i in range(n)       For all integers i in [0,n-1]...
...(i+1)                   ...evaluate p(i+1), so for all integers in [1,n]...
...%251                    ...and take modulo 251
...:[...]                  return as list
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/q1RVw6)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 224 bytes:

```
(n,t,s)->{int[]W=new int[t-1];for(int i=0;i<t-1;i++){W[i]=new java.util.Random().nextInt(251);};long[]O=new long[n];for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){long T=0;for(int h=1;h<t;h++){T+=W[h-1]*Math.pow(i,h);}O[i-1]=((T+s)%251);}return O;};
```

A Java 8 lambda expression. Outputs a comma separated integer array, and works perfectly until values in the output array reach beyond the range of the Java's `long`, or 64-bit signed integer, data type, upon which `-200` is output into the array.

[Try It Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/kKsNCP)

Comment: [195 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZFNT@MwEIbPza@YC8ImH2pCwwqZIO0JLVq2qK3UQ8jB25rG3XQc2VO6qOpv7zqhKxASl/H48cw7H17LFxmbVuF6@eeoN62xBGvPki3pJrkQwUfWSFx9Ztp0ZNFI5@BBatwHA42k7LNcKLjbNwZXZfXIPAOMOku9dVwcgkG7/d3oBTiS5I8Xo5ew8RrApmR1lwjSrhz3moM7uC@ODCOKHI9v953GvKwKVDvwfhnHVEW6oKgWz8YyoeP4dij4vNRvMe8zTSQuzYbxBNVf@oHEsjzlousTZoUuhtH4JNu3jtVJLwxvUIxLHadVwWah42ddXvc2K@piKOobEnwWFvOyri4eJNVJa3ZMR2FYc2EVbS3CWBzE0c8yXUhEZWHS1znd2PTVkdokGrnwMbtaN4pNklq6X77RnxoV4/0mBqdAs6Wk9WuiBtl3a@WrS8i8LY7dJ48@9/@EPPrC5zw8f8LzvqD/jkNwOKbXkEGaBVdwCWke5DCCb0HmWebhyMP8KriGHC5H/wA "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 205 bytes

\$ \text{205 bytes, It can be golfed much more.} \$

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZFLbtswEIb3PMVAQAAykYVItvKwqwBZFQ2MBKhdeGF4wSZ0xFQaGhQd1zC87x266abd9Cw9gO_RA2Ro0UFWLSBq8f8z37y-_2ruZSW7v6dRB81KWoxmu2-6XhjrYG8lS6er5KPEB1MzZj4_qXsH17BhAG69UPAeCuAf0MVw-AkoruDaWrmeDg0-zhiFPqg51FIjl_ax6Qd35KwmX_ThE2pHHA8FeJYV3PQ9-OfSzTsXuz8cYxc3orjaeG9SoFoFBJWbcddJxWBuLNfvOqewRGoYvLaZcC2KtvUE1VdH0TzLU7EdeM7dG86-UY6vmBScARRUz8K4OB3u9dLrAS9gMy7GJ3zCS6p0XEtXJguz4jouhUic8cDt4I5rcgs-PmnEEVUmZRuG-vs6K60ZUVma3_fzJJ_Dzketzkfrxqk60Sj2KatSVwp4yEpK2dzSaEONSoQFtlgk4CHoMLx447v_-M0__AUdzlXIb-gyQFdvRFJ_ac_Jo2kUQ_hmkWhTtsy_MPuP3XF6CRmkGTuDLqQ5y6EH5ywjLSOxR2J-xi4hh26vTXkB)

```scala
(n,t,s)=>{val W=new Array[Int](t-1);for(i<-0 until t-1){W(i)=Random.nextInt(251)};val O=new Array[Long](n);for(i<-1 to n){var T=0L;for(h<-1 until t) {T=T+(W(h-1)*math.pow(i,h)).toLong};O(i-1)=(T+s)%251};O}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVLRSuNAFAUf5ysOBWFG22DSxl2LLvi0rJQt2C59kD7M6tSMJpOSTFvL0i_xpS_6T_rir3ibmYbqwi6EkNxz7rn33Hsfn8trmcr2ev00s5PW19e9N51N88Kiigczq9PgUpqbPGMs_32nri3O8YcBdjlV-I4z8B_GNrF9CZx9w3lRyOVVLze3Y0bUGzVBJrXhsrgtux4d2EITLrr4ZbQlnY0oMJcpLrpO2DRBomUl6VCHjwg0auGFqOiYW7QQCs-Z5AW4xmkLR5gZcgAH1yLAiGuShXMWGPVgSYZHca2x2qnX_1CvssXN38VC2Bxmt8pcFhhS8lGvDlX0xNF9b7sZqPjDQ_ARsaqmD2h2Ngmm-YLrJhIhAptveqhzVvVXnxqpcmh4QxxuRrcPMvXJU5-5v3rgtGtjVOFt3sm5X_zAxflgWVqVBdqbXiQ6VeA-K0hk-ZMG2NNGiQ97MiS4JW1HLHZw-x-8_Ac-peuxqeEX9ZUE2b27Kd64ajThn3FDCLY1v2Ir5u7cn_v65SA8QYQwYsdoI4xZjA6-sIhiEQU7FIyP2QlitDsu5R0)

```scala
import scala.util.Random

object A {
  type G = (Int, Int, Int) => Array[Long]

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val J: G = (n, t, s) => {
      val W = new Array[Int](t - 1)
      for (i <- 0 until t - 1) {
        W(i) = Random.nextInt(251)
      }
      val O = new Array[Long](n)
      for (i <- 1 to n) {
        var T = 0L
        for (h <- 1 until t) {
          T = T+ (W(h - 1) * math.pow(i, h)).toLong
        }
        O(i - 1) = (T + s) % 251
      }
      O
    }

    val scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in)
    while (scanner.hasNextLine) {
      val n = scanner.nextInt()
      val t = scanner.nextInt()
      val s = scanner.nextInt()
      println(J(n, t, s).mkString("[", ", ", "]"))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 133 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat!

-1 byte thanks to @ceilingcat!

```c
v[999];i,j,k,l;f(n,t,s){for(i=t;--i;)v[i]=rand()%251;for(*v=s;n/++i;printf("%d ",s%251))for(s=j=0;j<t;s+=k)for(k=v[l=j++];l--;)k*=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCoMwEEDRdT2FCEJiJtQqLch0TiIuREmZaNNiQjbi2VPs9v836dc0pRT7rusGZLCwwIpGOAjg5W4@m2AKqDWjjD0PtI1uFrJs7jc8ZxXJo7sqxfjd2AUjinLOC/CnkPIknizVaJ8BvaLlnxaK/UpWqQFXrVEuFTEe6T2yEzLbs4sRD8hbyJu2lpgd6Qc)