# Do n and n^3 have the same set of digits?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

Given a number *n* (0 <= *n* <= 2642245), check if *n* and *n*<sup>3</sup> have the same set of digits, and output a truthy or falsey value accordingly.

For example, let's check the number 100.

100<sup>3</sup> is 1000000.

The set of digits in 100 is {0, 1}.

The set of digits in 1000000 is {0, 1}.

Therefore, 100 should give a truthy value.

#### Test cases

```
0 -> True
1 -> True
10 -> True
107624 -> True
251894 -> True
251895 -> False
102343 -> False
```

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

[OEIS A029795](http://oeis.org/A029795)

Comment: Proposed test case: **106239**

Comment: Test case: `2103869 -> True`. This (or a larger one) is necessary to test a language with a `long` datatype.

Comment: Too bad the max is too big for language without a 64 bit integer type.

Comment: I think you should be explicit about the **base**... in binary it's kinda half the fun :-D

Comment: @TheVee Decimal is the default base for challenges involving digits in numbers.

Comment: @Dennis why so many "upvotes"? I may have missed the point, but I'm interested.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt **106239** is the smallest positive integer **n** such that **n³** – **1199090390129919** – does not contain all digits of **n**. Some answers were only checking if **n** contained all digits of **n³** and thus got the wrong result for **106239**.

Comment: @Dennis ooooh, clever! Thanks!

Comment: @edc65 - Too bad the max is so small that 64-bit integers are sufficient.

Answer (score 29):

## Python 3, <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
lambda x:{*str(x)}=={*str(x**3)}
```

I think this only works in Python 3.5 and later.
Four bytes have gone, thanks to Copper.

Comment: @Emigna No, you wouldn't be able to add a string and an integer.

Comment: @daHugLenny You can't use the set(...) function, though.

Comment: In python 2 you can use backtics as a shortcut for repr(), saving 6 bytes. `set(\`x\`)`

Comment: @DenDenDo Any input larger than `2097152` (`sys.maxint**(1/3.)`) and less than `sys.maxint+1` will return `False` if you use `repr()`. https://repl.it/EXs2/1. Longs have an `L` at the end.

Comment: Untested, but you can probably do `lambda x:{*str(x)}=={*str(x**3)}` in Python 3.5+.

Comment: @Copper You can do that? I never realised! Thanks!

Comment: The `{*...}` trick is cool! But why does the code need to be prefixed with `lambda x:`? Is making it a function part of the question?

Comment: @BenHoyt It's more concise than using print(...) and input(). Making it a function is shorter than making a full program.

Comment: Because the question says returning a truthy or falsy value is enough, you can replace `==` by `^`. Two equal sets lead to `{}` which is falsy.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Wouldn't I then have to switch truthy and falsy around?

Comment: @J843136028: yes, of course, sigh. Never mind.

Comment: I suppose you could bitflip the falsy to make it truthy and vice versa... but then it would be the same number of characters.

Comment: I would specify that this works in python 3. **5** and after...

Comment: @Bakuriu I never realised. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

05AB1E uses [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding.

```
3mê¹êQ
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=M23DqsK5w6pR&input=MjUxODk0)

**Explanation**

```
3m       # input^3
  ê      # sorted with duplicates removed
     Q   # is equal to
   ¹ê    # input sorted with duplicates removed
```

Comment: @PuzomorCroatia: 05AB1E uses the [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding, so all these characters are 1 byte each. It is quite common for golfing languages to either use code pages with more printable characters than UTF-8 or alternatively create their own code page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, while trying to edit my comment, I deleted it. Just to make things clear to everyone, I asked about encoding of characters in code golfing languages

Comment: @Emigna 05AB1E technically uses its own code page, even though it's pretty much identical to CP-1252.

Answer (score 14):

## C, 73 bytes

```c
k;b(i){k=0;while(i)k|=1<<i%10,i/=10;return k;}f(n){return b(n)-b(n*n*n);}
```

Creates the set via bits. Returns `0` for same set, anything else for different sets.

Ungolfed:

```c
k;
b(i){
  k=0;
  while(i)
    k|=1<<i%10,
    i/=10;
  return k;
}

f(n){
  return b(n)-b(n*n*n);
}
```

Comment: The ungolfed code is missing `1 <<` when setting the bits with `k |= 1 << i % 10`. Great solution!

Comment: I used this bitmap idea to make a [39 byte x86-64 machine code function](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99781/do-n-and-n3-have-the-same-set-of-digits/100112#100112) :)

Comment: Are we allowed to consider `0` as truthy?  I guess `strcmp` works that way, so it seems reasonable in C.

Comment: This only works for the entire range of inputs required by the question if `int` larger than 64-bit.  (Even signed 64-bit is not enough, but unsigned 64-bit is).  So there are no real implementations of C that I know of where this satisfies the question's requirements.  (It does work correctly with `unsigned long long`, or just `unsigned long` in implementations where that's a 64-bit type).  GNU C defines `__int128_t` on 64-bit machines (without any headers)...

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, 31 + 2 (`-pl` flag) = <s>25</s> <s>21</s> <s>18</s> <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
$_=($==$_**3)!~/[^$_]/*!/[^$=]/
```

Using:

```
perl -ple '$_=($==$_**3)!~/[^$_]/*!/[^$=]/' <<< 251894
```

Output: `1\n` or `0\n`.

Thanx to @Dada for 3 bytes, Gabriel Benamy for 1 byte, & @Zaid for bug reports.

Comment: Nice answer! You can still save a few (3) bytes : `perl -pe '$_=$_**3!~/[^$_]/'`

Comment: @Zaid Thanx. Fixed.

Comment: Now it outputs false for `10` :(

Comment: @Zaid Yep. `-l` flag needed.

Comment: Change the `&&` to a `*` to save a byte

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 34 bytes

```
f=Union@*IntegerDigits;f@#==f[#^3]&
```

Direct implementation (unnamed function of one integer argument).

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
,3*\D‘ṬE
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=LDMqXETigJjhuaxF&input=&args=MTA2MjM5) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=LDMqXETigJjhuaxFCsW8w4figqxH&input=&args=MTAwLCAwLCAxLCAxMCwgMTA3NjI0LCAyNTE4OTQsIDI1MTg5NSwgMTAyMzQzLCAxMDYyMzksIDIxMDM4NjksIDE2NTY0).

#### How it works

```
,3*\D‘ṬE  Main link. Argument: n

,3        Pair; yield [n, 3].
  *\      Cumulative reduce by exponentation. Yields [n, n³].
    D     Decimal; yield the digit arrays of n and n³.
     ‘    Increment, mapping 0 ... 9 to 1 ... 10.
      Ṭ   Untruth (vectorizes); map digit array [a, b, c, ...] to the smallest
          of zeroes with ones at indices a, b, c, ...
       E  Test the results for equality.
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>55</s> 51 bytes

Thanks to Downgoat for 3 bytes! You can save a byte by converting to ES7 and using `n**3` instead of `n*n*n`.

```
n=>(f=s=>[...new Set(s+[])].sort()+[])(n)==f(n*n*n)
```

Simple enough.

Comment: it's terrible that there isn't a nicer way to compare sets for equivalence

Comment: @njzk2 Well, I'd say the greater tragedy is that `==` doesn't work even on arrays.

Comment: You can save a byte by changing `n*n*n` to `n**3`, but I guess that might be ES7 and not ES6.

Comment: Perhaps use `\`${[...new Set( ... ).sort()}\`` if that saves bytes

Comment: @Downgoat Thanks, that inspired me to save some more bytes!

Comment: The last parenthesis is too many, isn't it?

Comment: @Huntro Indeed it is. I copied that from my testing environment, which surrounds the expression in parens.

Comment: This fails for `2103869`, and the problem explicitly requires solutions to work up to `2642245`.

Comment: @user5090812 Shouldn't this because of the precision in JS cannot handle number of that size? Say `2103869**3 = 9.30E+18 > 2**53`

Comment: Does ```n=>(f=s=>[...new Set(s+[])].sort()+9)(n)==f(n*n*n)``` work as we don't require the compared string be pure?

Answer (score 6):

### CJam, 8 bytes

```
l_~3#s^!
```

[Test suite.](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4vezpMOwoKTF9-MyNzXiEKCl1ufS8&input=MAoxCjEwCjEwNzYyNAoyNTE4OTQKMjUxODk1CjEwMjM0Mw)

#### Explanation

```
l   e# Read input.
_~  e# Duplicate and evaluate.
3#  e# Raise to third power.
s   e# Convert back to string.
^   e# Symmetric set difference. Gives an empty list iff the two sets
    e# are equal.
!   e# Logical NOT.
```

Answer (score 6):

## C#, <s>241</s> <s>208</s> <s>205</s> <s>201</s> <s>193</s> <s>233</s> <s>222</s> <s>220</s> <s>212</s> <s>203</s> <s>177</s> 159 bytes (109 alternate)

```
I=>{x=s=>{var a=new int[10];foreach(var h in s+"")a[h-'0']++;return a;};var i=x(I);var j=x(I*I*I);for(var k=0;k<10;)if(i[k]>0^j[k++]>0)return 0>1;return 1>0;};
```

The lambda's must specifically use the `ulong` type:

```
System.Func<ulong, bool> b; // = I=>{...};
System.Func<ulong, int[]> x; // inner lambda
```

Thanks to @Corak and @Dennis_E for saving some bytes, and @TimmyD for finding a problem with my original solution.  Thanks to @SaxxonPike for pointing out the ulong/long/decimal/etc problem (which actually also saved me some bytes).

---

There is also a **109 byte** solution using HashSets, similar to the Java answers here, but I'm going to stick to my original solution for my score.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;I=>{return new HashSet<char>(I+"").SetEquals(new HashSet<char>(I*I*I+""));};
```

Comment: Can you check `p<0` instead of `p==1`?

Comment: @TuukkaX Would've done that, but the way I'm determining the sets now is using the same array of integers, incrementing the appropriate index for both strings, so a value of 0 or 2 is okay, but if any are 1, it should return false.

Comment: Save very little by extracting the creation and filling of the arrays into a separate lambda: `n=>{Func<string,int[]>x=s=>{var a=new int[10];foreach(var c in s)a[int.Parse(c+"")]++;return a;};var i=x(n);var j=x((long)Math.Pow(int.Parse(n),3)+"");for(var k=0;k<10;)if(i[k]>0^j[k++]>0)return 0>1;return 1>0;};`

Comment: You can replace `int.Parse(c+"")` with `c-'0'`

Comment: Fails test case 2103869. I ran into the same issue. (Nevermind, I found out why. I'd used a `long` instead of `ulong` and this test case uses the MSB.)

Comment: @SaxxonPike So it turns out if I take the input as a `ulong` instead of a `string`, it works.  The problem is with `Math.Pow()` returning a `double`, so if I just do `I*I*I` it works as long as `I` is a `ulong`.  It actually saves bytes doing it this way too because no more `Math.Pow()` call ^.^

Answer (score 6):

## Java 8, 154 characters

```
a->java.util.Arrays.equals((a+"").chars().distinct().sorted().toArray(),(new java.math.BigInteger(a+"").pow(3)+"").chars().distinct().sorted().toArray());
```

Called like this:

```
interface Y {
    boolean n(int x);
}

static Y y = a->java.util.Arrays.equals((a+"").chars().distinct().sorted().toArray(),(new java.math.BigInteger(a+"").pow(3)+"").chars().distinct().sorted().toArray());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(y.n(0));
    System.out.println(y.n(1));
    System.out.println(y.n(10));
    System.out.println(y.n(107624));
    System.out.println(y.n(251894));
    System.out.println(y.n(251895));
    System.out.println(y.n(102343));
}
```

Outputs:

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
false
```

A very Java 8-y answer, using a lambda as well as streams including some fancy number-to-string conversions.

Unfortunately we need to use `BigInteger.pow(3)` instead of `Math.pow(a,3)` due to Math.pow using non-precise doubles, which return incorrect values with large numbers (starting with `2103869`).

Comment: That `static Y y` thing is a weird initialisation syntax, does it autoassign to `y.n` because the interface has exactly one member?

Comment: I believe so, yes. To be honest I'm newish to Java 8 since my workplace is still on 7, but that's how I perceive it to work.

Comment: The compiler automatically adds the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation (interface with only one method, see javadoc) which makes lambdas work instead of the usual anonymous type instantiation.

Comment: This is essentially equal to `Y y = new Y() { @Override public boolean n(int x) { return Arrays.equals((a+"").chars().distinct().sorted().toArray(),(new BigInteger(a+"").pow(3)+"").chars().distinct().sorted().toArray()); } }` and the `static`modifier is only there to allow calling `y.n(int)` from the static main method.

Comment: Why not `a*a*a` instead of `.pow()`?

Comment: Oh, just realized signed 64-bit isn't enough :(

Comment: Nice answer! +1 Btw, imports/usings are unfortunately also part of the byte-count, so it should be `a->java.util.Arrays.equals((a+"").chars().distinct().sorted().toArray(),(new java.math.BigInteger(a+"").pow(3)+"").chars().distinct().sorted().toArray());`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I was under the impression that that would only be necessary for full programs?

Comment: Nevermind, just read the meta post about this and it seems the community agrees. I suppose I can see why. I will update.

Comment: Nice solution! You can use [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHBTsMwDIbveQprp0SwaGu3AZpAghsHTjtNiIOXhi4lTUriblRoz16iqmc6n2z99mf/coUnnPtGu6r46pv2YI0CZTFGeEPj4JcZRzp8otKwTxWkOHhvNTpwPGnwI7bswlgkpDS6hw4eocf5U5XAsiVj5XMI2EWpv1u0kXO8mc2EVEcMkQtZmEjGKUpp9IF0kRLywwgXt9zpMwykGukoX0z5ms4pdRgpjT/zXFwPFP2WsdHlePHJmwLq5JXvKBhXvn8AhjKK0eyui6Rr6VuSTZLJOt5Jxxci2f5HX07pk4DF3SZbTTRl6@X9w1VN68l1Wb7KxfDLS/8H) to share your answer. It even counts your answer as 1 Byte shorter.

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 47 bytes

```haskell
n%p=[c|c<-['0'..],elem c$show$n^p]
f n=n%1==n%3
```

Very slow. Test with `c<-['0'..'9']`.

Tests every character for inclusion in the string representation of `n`, and makes a list of those included. Does likewise for `n^3` and checks if the lists are equal.

Comment: Does Haskell not have set literals, or a function which returns the unique elements from a list?

Comment: @cat No. Haskell has `nub` (get unique elements) and `sort`, but both require the lengthy import `import Data.List`. Even so, it comes very close at 48 bytes: `import Data.List;q=sort.nub.show;f n=q n==q(n^3)`.

Comment: Why the need to sort...?

Comment: @cat `nub` preserves order by first appearance, i.e. `nub [3,1,3,2,1,2] == [3,1,2]`. It doesn't convert to a set type (there is none), but gives a list.

Comment: Oh, I never realised Haskell doesn't have a primitive unordered collection type, that makes sense

Answer (score 6):

## BASH, <del>69</del>, 59 bytes

*UPDATE*

Another nice way to do this in bash is to use *tr* (62 bytes, but can probably be squeezed a bit more)

```
T() { m=`bc<<<$1^3`;[ -z "`tr -d $m <<<$1;tr -d $1 <<<$m`" ];}
```

*EDIT:* Some more optimizations (Thx ! @manatwork)

**Golfed**

```
T() { S(){ fold -1|sort -u;};bc<<<$1^3|S|diff - <(S<<<$1);}
```

**Test**

```
TEST() {
 T $1 >/dev/null; echo $?
}

TEST 0
0
TEST 1
0
TEST 11
1
TEST 10
0
TEST 107624
0
TEST 251894
0
TEST 251895
1
TEST 102343
1
TEST 106239
1
```

0 - for success (exit code)
1 - for failure (exit code)

Comment: I'm afraid the base theory is completely wrong here. Try `T <<< 11`. Will say the digit sets are the same just because 11**3 == 1331 contains the digits not present in the original number twice.

Comment: Yep, you are correct, fixed ! Thank you !

Comment: Ok, but now some extra spaces left in the code. Not sure why you added the `-w` explicitly to `fold`. If `uniq` is used without options, `sort -u` can replace it. And feed the 2nd S call with here-string. And I think there is no need to quote the formula passed to `bc`.

Comment: @manatwork, thx, I've fixed the fold argument, removed spaces, and made the second diff argument use a here-doc.

I now also pipe the first argument into _diff_, and have removed the superfluous quotes around the _bc_ expression.

>uniq is used without options, sort -u can replace it.
That's just a remnants of previous version (was _uniq -u_)).

Thank you !

Comment: @zeppelin: you can use `cmp` instead of `diff` and save 1 byte.

Comment: @Ipor - that's a nice idea, I will look into this, thx !

Answer (score 6):

## x86-64 machine code function, 40 bytes.

## Or 37 bytes if 0 vs. non-zero is allowed as "truthy", like strcmp.

Thanks to Karl Napf's C answer for the bitmap idea, which x86 can do very efficiently with [BTS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BTS.html).

Function signature: `_Bool cube_digits_same(uint64_t n);`, using the x86-64 System V ABI.  (`n` in RDI, boolean return value (0 or 1) in AL).

`_Bool` is defined by ISO C11, and is typically used by `#include <stdbool.h>` to define `bool` with the same semantics as C++ `bool`.

Potential savings:

- 3 bytes:  Returning the inverse condition (non-zero if there's a difference).  Or from inline asm: returning a flag condition (which is possible with gcc6)
- 1 byte:   If we could clobber EBX (doing so would give this function a non-standard calling convention). (could do that from inline asm)
- 1 byte:   the RET instruction (from inline asm)

All of these are possible if this was an inline-asm fragment instead of a function, which would make it **35 bytes for inline-asm**.

```
0000000000000000 <cube_digits_same>:
   0:   89 f8           mov    eax,edi
   2:   48 f7 e7        mul    rdi          # can't avoid a REX prefix: 2642245^2 doesn't fit in 32 bits
   5:   48 f7 e7        mul    rdi          # rax = n^3, rdx=0
   8:   44 8d 52 0a     lea    r10d,[rdx+0xa]  # EBX would save a REX prefix, but it's call-preserved in this ABI.
   c:   8d 4a 02        lea    ecx,[rdx+0x2]

000000000000000f <cube_digits_same.repeat>:
   f:   31 f6           xor    esi,esi

0000000000000011 <cube_digits_same.cube_digits>:
  11:   31 d2           xor    edx,edx
  13:   49 f7 f2        div    r10         ; rax = quotient.  rdx=LSB digit
  16:   0f ab d6        bts    esi,edx     ; esi |= 1<<edx
  19:   48 85 c0        test   rax,rax     ; Can't skip the REX: (2^16 * 10)^3 / 10 has all-zero in the low 32.
  1c:   75 f3           jne    11 <cube_digits_same.cube_digits>

                                         ; 1st iter:                 2nd iter:                both:
  1e:   96              xchg   esi,eax   ; eax=n^3 bitmap            eax=n bitmap             esi=0
  1f:   97              xchg   edi,eax   ; edi=n^3 bitmap, eax=n     edi=n bmp, eax=n^3 bmp
  20:   e2 ed           loop   f <cube_digits_same.repeat>

  22:   39 f8           cmp    eax,edi
  24:   0f 94 d0        sete   al
                  ;; The ABI says it's legal to leave garbage in the high bytes of RAX for narrow return values
                  ;; so leaving the high 2 bits of the bitmap in AH is fine.
  27:   c3              ret    
0x28: end of function.
```

LOOP seems like the smallest way to repeat once.  I also looked at just repeating the loop (without REX prefixes, and a different bitmap register), but that's slightly larger.  I also tried using PUSH RSI, and using `test spl, 0xf` / `jz` to loop once (since the ABI requires that RSP is 16B aligned before CALL, so one push aligns it, and another misaligns it again).  There's no `test r32, imm8` encoding, so the smallest way was with a 4B TEST instruction (including a REX prefix) to test just the low byte of RSP against an imm8.  Same size as LEA + LOOP, but with extra PUSH/POP instructions required.

Tested for all n in the test range, vs. steadybox's C implementation (since it uses a different algorithm).  In the two cases of different results that I looked at, my code was correct and steadybox's was wrong.  I think my code is correct for all n.

```
_Bool cube_digits_same(unsigned long long n);

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{
    for(unsigned n=0 ; n<= 2642245 ; n++) {
        bool c = f(n);
        bool asm_result = cube_digits_same(n);
        if (c!=asm_result)
            printf("%u problem: c=%d asm=%d\n", n, (int)c, (int)asm_result);
    }
}
```

The only lines printed have c=1 asm=0: false-positives for the C algorithm.

Also tested against a `uint64_t` version of Karl's C implementation of the same algorithm, and the results match for all inputs.

Comment: Code golf in *machine code*? That's true mastery!

Comment: @chx: It's really in assembly language, optimizing for code size.  I don't write the hex bytes directly, I just know (or check on) what size each instruction is.  (What I posted is from assembling with yasm and then running `objdump -drwC -Mintel` on the object file, and copying comments).  It's a language where optimizing for code size is actually useful in real life.  (But even then, only in rare cases like bootloaders or demos.  Usually it's only worth saving code size when it doesn't hurt performance in the already-cached case, but then it is useful avoid decode bottlenecks + cache misses)

Comment: @chx: but yes, golfing in asm does make me feel like a badass, thanks for noticing :)  See my other answers, here and on SO :)

Comment: I am a *very* old hat in assembly (1987, Z80 was the first) but I would've never thought to enter into code golf with that. I would've thought impossible.

Comment: @chx: I only golf occasionally, usually only when I see one in Hot Network Questions that looks reasonable for asm.  Usually stuff with numbers, not strings.  A few other people do golf in asm, though.  I hadn't thought of doing so myself until I saw someone else's machine-code golf answer.  Might have been [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77334/30206) that clued me in to the fact that you can count machine code bytes instead of asm source characters for asm answers.  anatolyg has posted some, including on this question.

Comment: Nice work, that BTS instruction really saves the day!

Comment: @KarlNapf: yeah, IDK why compilers don't use it more often.  It's fast on Intel CPUs with a register destination.  (1 uop, 1c latency, can run on multiple ALU execution ports on Intel SnB-family ([source](http://agner.org/optimize/)).  It's 2 m-ops on AMD Bulldozer-family, but that's still cheap.  The funny thing about it is how slow it is with a memory destination: cheaper to load / bts / store separately, because of its crazy-CISC bitstring behaviour with a memory operand: the address read/written  depends on the source operand!

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, <s>54</s> 52 bytes

Thanks @Laikoni for saving two bytes.

```
(%)=all.flip elem
k n|[a,b]<-show<$>[n,n^3]=b%a&&a%b
```

Comment: Declaring `a%b=all(`elem`a)b` as a function and then calling with `b%a&&a%b` should save two bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 10 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
⍕≡⍕∪(⍕*∘3)
```

`⍕≡` is the argument's text representation identical to

`⍕∪` the union of the argument's text representation and

`(⍕*∘3)` the text representation of the cubed argument?

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395pp%u219017%20%u22C4%20f%u2190%u2355%u2261%u2355%u222A%28%u2355*%u22183%29%20%u22C4%20f%A80%201%2010%20107624%20251894%20251895%20102343&run)

**Note:** For large numbers, set `⎕PP←34 ⋄ ⎕FR←1287` (34 significant digits, 128 bit floats)

Comment: You're assuming that the unique digits in n^3 can't be fewer than those in n?

Comment: Can you prove the existence of a counter-example?

Comment: 106239, see comments at the top

Answer (score 5):

## Clojure, 35 bytes

```
#(=(set(str %))(set(str(* % % %))))
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java 7, <s>185</s> 178 characters

```
import java.util.*;
boolean a(int n){return new HashSet(Arrays.asList((n+"").split(""))).equals(new HashSet(Arrays.asList((new java.math.BigInteger(n+"").pow(3)+"").split(""))));}
```

Call as:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println(0 + " -> " + a(0));
    System.out.println(1 + " -> " + a(1));
    System.out.println(10 + " -> " + a(10));
    System.out.println(107624 + " -> " + a(107624));
    System.out.println(2103869 + " -> " + a(2103869));
    System.out.println(251894 + " -> " + a(251894));
    System.out.println(251895 + " -> " + a(251895));
    System.out.println(102343 + " -> " + a(102343));
    System.out.println(106239 + " -> " + a(106239));
}
```

Output:

```
0 -> true
1 -> true
10 -> true
107624 -> true
2103869 -> true
251894 -> true
251895 -> false
102343 -> false
106239 -> false
```

*(I'm never sure if I have to count imports and method definitions as well... I've seen either way. The code itself would be only 141 bytes long though.)*

Comment: Imports/usings are indeed part of the byte-count. You can remove the `static ` though.

Comment: Okay thanks. Removed `static`.

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>65</s> <s>79</s> 70 bytes

Takes `n` from stdin, splits `n` and `n^3` into single digits, and compares the two sets. Uses the `gmp` package to handle large integers (thanks to Billywob for pointing out that shortcoming). Now uses `substring` to cut up `n` and `n^3`, thanks to @MickyT for the suggestion. (Previous versions used `scan` and `gsub` in a hacky way.)

```
s=substring
setequal(s(n<-gmp::as.bigz(scan()),p<-1:1e2,p),s(n^3,p,p))
```

Comment: Sadly this wont work (for large `n`) unless you use some kind of BigInt package. See `?.Machine` for details on the biggest integer and float etc. To see this compare e.g. `2600001^3` in R to [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2600001%5E3)

Comment: I've never had to use it myself but it seems like the `gmp` package could solve this problem.

Comment: Ah, good catch! I've updated the answer, it now uses `gmp::as.bigz()` to handle large integers.

Comment: you could make use of the fact substring converts to a character to split the number, eg `s=substring;setequal(s(n<-gmp::as.bigz(scan()),p<-1:1e4,p),s(n^3,p,p))`

Comment: @MickyT Fantastic suggestion! I didn't know `substring` could be used that way (I've only ever used `substr`). Answer has been edited to incorporate your suggestion now.

Comment: Given the range of possible inputs, `p<-1:99` (or even `p<-1:20`) is sufficient, yielding -1 byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
*3ṢQ⁼ṢQ$
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=KjPhuaJR4oG84bmiUSQ&input=&args=MTAw)

Explanation:

```
       $    # As a monadic (single argument) link:
    ⁼       # Return true if the following are equal
     ṢQ     # The unique sorted elements of 'n'
  ṢQ        # and The unique sorted elements
*3          # of 'n^3'
```

Comment: This doesn't work with input **100**.

Comment: I understand why it doesn't, but why doesn't [this work](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=KjPhuaJR4oG84bmiUQ&input=&args=MTAw)?

Comment: Because Jelly is strictly parsed left to right, without operator precedence. `*3ṢQ⁼ṢQ$` works as intended, since the quick `$` groups the two atoms to its left into a monadic chain.

Answer (score 4):

## C++, 82 bytes

```
t(int a){int b=a*a*a,c,d;while(a|b)c|=1<<a%10,a/=10,d|=1<<b%10,b/=10;return c==d;}
```

The function t(a) returns the answer. Uses an int as a set. Printed nicely:

```
t(int a)
{
    int b = a*a*a, c, d;
    while(a|b) c|=1 << a%10, a/=10, d|=1 << b%10, b/=10;
    return c==d;
}
```

Comment: You need to include `#include<set>` and `using namespace std;` in the golfed code and byte count

Comment: @cat `#include<set>` instead of `algorithm`

Comment: @KarlNapf oh, I thought all the stdlib containers were acessible through algorithm -- shows what I know about C++ :)

Comment: It seems to me the variable local to the function "c"  is not initialized but used c|=1 ...

Answer (score 4):

## C++14, 93 bytes

```c++
int b(auto i){int k=0;while(i)k|=1<<i%10,i/=10;return k;}int f(auto n){return b(n)-b(n*n*n);}
```

Port of my [C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99836/53667), works for big numbers (call with `L` suffix).

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

Because we don't have enough variety with Pyth answers, let's add not one, but two more!  Both are 10 bytes, and have been tested with `106239` as a sample input (which some other answers failed).

```
!s.++Q,`**
```

Explanation:

```
!s.++Q,`**QQQQ   Implicit input filling
        **QQQ    Q ^ 3
       `         repr(Q^3)
      ,      Q   [repr(Q^3),Q]
    +Q           [Q,repr(Q^3),Q]
  .+             Deltas ([Digits in Q but not in Q^3, digits in Q^3 but not in Q])
!s               Are both empty?
```

[Try the first answer using an online test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21s.%2B%2BQ%2C%60%2a%2a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=106239%0A0%0A1%0A10%0A107624%0A251894%0A251895%0A102343&debug=0)

Second answer:

```
qFmS{`d,**
```

Explanation:

```
qFmS{`d,**QQQQ   Implicit input filling
        **QQQ    Q ^ 3
       ,     Q   [Q^3, Q]
  m              map over each element d of [Q^3, Q]:
     `d           the element's string representation
    {             with duplicates removed
   S              and sorted
qF               Fold over equality (are the two the same?)
```

[Try the second answer using an online test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qFmS%7B%60d%2C%2a%2a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=106239%0A0%0A1%0A10%0A107624%0A251894%0A251895%0A102343&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## Kotlin: 46/88/96 bytes

The question doesn't specify from where the input comes from, so here's the usual 3 input sources.

---

#### Function: 46 bytes

```
fun f(i:Long)="$i".toSet()=="${i*i*i}".toSet()
```

---

#### main() using first program argument: 88 bytes

`fun main(a:Array<String>){val i=a[0].toLong();println("$i".toSet()=="${i*i*i}".toSet())}`

---

#### main() using standard input: 96 bytes

`fun main(a:Array<String>){val i=readLine()!!.toLong();println("$i".toSet()=="${i*i*i}".toSet())}`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The input/output is implicitly specified because of the [tag:code-golf]. You can see the community-consensus standards [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963). Your function count should be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 44 bytes

```
g=n=>n<1?0:g(n/10)|1<<n%10
n=>g(n)==g(n*n*n)
```

Port of @KarlNapf's excellent C answer. ES7 saves a byte via `n**3`. Only works up to 208063 due to JavaScript's limited numeric precision; if you only need it to work up to 1290, you can save another byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 22 bytes

```perl6
{!(.comb⊖$_³.comb)}
```

### Expanded:

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
  !(
    .comb # get a list of the graphemes ( digits )

    ⊖ # Symmetric Set difference

    $_³.comb # cube and get a list of the graphemes
  )
}
```

The [Symmetric Set difference ｢⊖｣ operator](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/(%5E)) returns an empty [Set](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Set) if both sides are equivalent Sets (automatically turns a list into a Set). At that point the only thing left to do is invert it logically.

Comment: You can replace the `$_` with just `.`

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 48 bytes

```
->n{(f=->x{x.to_s.chars.uniq.sort})[n]==f[n**3]}
```

Comment: Shaved 6 bytes: `->n{(f=->x{x.digits.sort|[]})[n]==f[n**3]}`

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>94</s> 93 bytes

```
filter f($n){-join("$n"[0..99]|sort|select -u)}
(f($x=$args[0]))-eq(f("[bigint]$x*$x*$x"|iex))
```

*(Newline for clarity, not included in bytecount)*

The first line defines `f` as a `filter` (similar-ish enough to a function for our purposes here to not go into specifics) that takes input `$n` and does the following:

```
filter f($n){-join("$n"[0..99]|sort|select -u)}
       f($n)                                    # Input
                   "$n"                         # Cast as string
                       [0..99]                  # Index as char-array
                              |sort             # Sorted alphabetically
                                   |select -u   # Only select the -Unique elements
             -join(                          )  # Join those back together into a string
                                                 # Implicit return
```

The second line takes the input `$args`, performs `f` on it, and checks whether it's `-eq`ual to `f` performed on `$x` cubed. Note the explicit `[bigint]` cast, required else we'll get the result back in scientific notation, which will obviously not work.

The Boolean result is left on the pipeline, and output is implicit.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 0,1,10,107624,251894,251895,102343,106239,2103869|%{"$_ --> "+(.\do-n-n3-same-digits.ps1 $_)}
0 --> True
1 --> True
10 --> True
107624 --> True
251894 --> True
251895 --> False
102343 --> False
106239 --> False
2103869 --> True
```

*Saved a byte thanks to @ConnorLSW*

Comment: you can use `"$n"[0..99]` instead of `[char[]]"$n"` to save one byte, since the biggest number you'll need to deal with is only about 20 chars in length.

Comment: @ConnorLSW There's that indexing trick again. I'm going to need to remember that.

Comment: as long as you're guaranteed to be using less than 100 characters it's an easy enough save over the normal `char[]` conversion, the rest of your code is as good as I could get it, if there was a shorthand way to compare arrays, you could use something like `("$n"[0..99]|group).Name` to save loads but `compare` isn't exactly quick and easy to golf.

Comment: That's what I get for solving it without looking at the answers ... Pretty much [the same answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100286/15) ;-). But you missed a few very obvious optimizations ;-)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 47 bytes

```
import Data.Set
s=fromList.show
f n=s n==s(n^3)
```

Usage example: `f 102343` -> `False`.

Uses sets from the `Data.Set` module. The helper function `s` turns a number into its string representation and than makes a set out of the characters.

Comment: Can't you save a byte here using `s$n^3`?

Comment: @ais523: No, because it translates to `(s n==s) (n^3)` which gives a type error.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
doI,?:3^doI
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=ZG9JLD86M15kb0k&input=MTAyMzQz)

Thanks to @DestructibleWatermelon for pointing out a problem with my original answer.

#### Explanation

```
(?)doI,           I is the Input sorted with no duplicates
       ?:3^       Compute Input^3
           doI    Input^3 sorted with no duplicates is I
```

Comment: I like the cat smiley in this :3

Answer (score 3):

## Groovy, 35 <s>51</s> chars/bytes

I was sad not to see Groovy included, so here's my original 51-byte attempt:

`def x(def n){"$n".toSet()=="${n.power(3)}".toSet()}`

Rewritten as a 35-byte anonymous closure and with `**` for exponentiation, thanks to manatwork:

`{"$it".toSet()=="${it**3}".toSet()}`

Some test cases for the original function:

```
println x(0)
println x(1)
println x(10)
println x(107624)
println x(251894)
println x(251895)
println x(102343)
```

A named closure `c` could be called like this: `println c.call(107624)`. The anonymous 35-byte closure could be called like this: `println ({"$it".toSet()=="${it**3}".toSet()}(107624))`

Outputs:

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
false
```

Please note: I learned that something like code golf exists just now, so hopefully I got this right!

Comment: Hello Rado, and Welcome to PPCG! This is a great first answer, +1!

Comment: I managed to squeeze it even further to 47 chars/bytes by using a closure, but can't edit my previous answer due to being new here, so here it is:
`def c={"$it".toSet()=="${it.power(3)}".toSet()}`

Comment: Anonymous functions are acceptable. And use the `**` operator for exponentiation.

Comment: Thanks @NoOneIsHere! Also, calling the closure for test cases would involve replacing `x(107624)` with `c.call(107624)`

Comment: Thank you @manatwork! Using an anonymous closure and `**` brings it down to beautiful 35 chars/bytes: `{"$it".toSet()=="${it**3}".toSet()}`

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 55 bytes

Takes input on the command line.
Makes n into a character class and tests the string n ^ 3 against it.

```
a=arg[1]print(not("%u"):format(a^3):find("[^"..a.."]"))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Factor, 37 bytes

```
[ dup 3 ^ [ 10 >base unique ] bi@ = ]
```

(passing) Tests:

```
: func ( x -- ? ) dup 3 ^ [ number>string unique ] bi@ = ;
{ t } [ 0 func ] unit-test
{ t } [ 1 func ] unit-test
{ t } [ 10 func ] unit-test
{ t } [ 107624 func ] unit-test
{ t } [ 251894 func ] unit-test
{ f } [ 251895 func ] unit-test
{ f } [ 102343 func ] unit-test
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 86 characters

```
using System.Linq;i=>(i*i*i+"").All((i+"").Contains)&&(i+"").All((i*i*i+"").Contains);
```

Because it is a lambda, in practical use, you will need to assign it to type `Func<decimal, bool>`. This should, according to MSDN, be useful until you go beyond 28 digits on the `i*i*i` calculation. If you use the BigInteger package, you can theoretically go to however many digits you have memory for. Just substitute `BigInteger` for `decimal`. The function itself does not change.

nUnit Test:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace CodeGolf
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class CodeGolfTestFixture
    {
        [TestCase(0, true)]
        [TestCase(1, true)]
        [TestCase(10, true)]
        [TestCase(107624, true)]
        [TestCase(251894, true)]
        [TestCase(251895, false)]
        [TestCase(102343, false)]
        [TestCase(106239, false)]
        [TestCase(2103869, true)]
        public void Test(int inp, bool expectedResult)
        {
            Func<decimal, bool> subject = i => 
                (i*i*i + "").All((i + "").Contains) &&
                (i + "").All((i*i*i + "").Contains);
            var observedResult = subject(inp);
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, observedResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some other C# golfing exercises do not have `using System.Linq`. I'd like to discuss its requirement. For example: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84789/62301

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 32 bytes

```
[ dup 3 ^ [ present ] bi@ set= ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYy9CsIwGEV3n@I@QWnS1l8EN3FxEadSIcavtNSmMfkyiPjssRZxuYd7hlMrzYOL59PhuF@jI2fojl5xk9TBaG4H42EdeTIMTzwd5qd17SQegYwmj83shRQCYpx0MZc5ZCGWqx@KUcosz/COJW7BIsMF5b9b4druvvUtqtgrC89Kd0n8AA)

- `dup` Make a copy of the input.

  **Stack (e.g.):** `100 100`
- `3 ^` Cube.

  **Stack:** `100 1000000`
- `[ present ] bi@` Convert them both to strings.

  **Stack:** `"100" "1000000"`
- `set=` Are they equal when viewed as sets?

  **Stack:** `t`

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
3e⊍
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=3e%E2%8A%8D&inputs=102343&header=&footer=)

An empty set is truthy and a set with items is falsey. If that ain't an acceptable format for output:

### 4 bytes

```
3e⊍¬
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=3e%E2%8A%8D%C2%AC&inputs=251894&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```
3e⊍
3e  # input ^ 3
  ⊍ # symmetric set difference between the above and input
    # ¬ will negate that result, making it either `0` or `1`
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 10 bytes

```
3^`}SR`}Sq
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=3%5E%60%7DSR%60%7DSq&input=251894)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

It was difficult for me to find a function to convert to a string while searching the online tutorial. I just guessed `` ` `` and was right. I suppose [this site](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/) is better for searching.

```
q.{`^Q3.{`
```

[**Try it online**](http://pyth.tryitonline.net/#code=cS57YF5RMy57YA&input=MjUxODk0)

**Explanation**

```
     Q          evaluated input (implicit Q at the end as well)
    ^  3        cubed
   `      `     str() - it's actually repr, but doesn't have an 'L' at the end of longs
 .{     .{      convert each string to set()
q               check if equal
                implicit print
```

Comment: `vz` is Q and you can remove the last `z`

Comment: srry you need a ` instead of the z

Comment: still get 10 tho

Comment: also the tutorial is *super* out of date, I would recommend using the table at https://pyth.herokuapp.com/ which is always current.

Comment: to the third power, you can overflow the repr

Comment: @Maltysen I already linked that in my answer.

Comment: @njzk2 This works differently than Python's. There is *still* no `L`, even if the result is a long. Try it yourself with input of `2103869`.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 202

```
@set/an=%1,c=n*n*n,e=1
@for /l %%a in (0,1,9)do @call:l %%a
@exit/b%e%
:l
@set f=1
@call set s=%%n:%1=%%
@if "%s%"=="%n%" set/af=1-f
@call set s=%%c:%1=%%
@if "%s%"=="%c%" set/af=1-f
@set/ae*=f
```

Note: Only works up to 1290 due to the limited range of Batch's data type. Takes input on the command line and returns an error level of 1 if the cube uses the same set of digits, 0 otherwise. Works by looping through each digit, checking to see whether an even number of the two strings contains the digit.

Answer (score 1):

## [DASH](https://github.com/molarmanful/DASH), 33 bytes

```
@=(f\ss[sort I;unq;str])#0f ^#0 3
```

Usage:

```
(@=(f\ss[sort I;unq;str])#0f ^#0 3)500
```

## Explanation

```
@                         
  =                       #. check if the following are equal
    (f\                   #. store the following to f:
      ss[sort I;unq;str]  #. composition of to string, unique, sort
    )
      #0                  #. apply f to the arg
    f ^ #0 3              #. apply f to arg cubed
```

Answer (score 1):

## ES6 (Javascript), <del>32</del>, 58 bytes

**Golfed**

```
n=>(x=(a,b)=>!RegExp(`[^${a}]`).test(b))(m=n*n*n,n)&x(n,m)
```

**Test**

```
N=n=>(x=(a,b)=>!RegExp(`[^${a}]`).test(b))(m=n*n*n,n)&x(n,m)

N(0)
1 (true)

N(1)
1 (true)

N(10)
1 (true)

N(107624)
1 (true)

N(251894)
1 (true)

N(251895)
0 (false)

N(102343)
0 (false)

N(106239)
0 (false)
```

Comment: You need to check set equality, not just subset - see Dennis' comment on the main post for the test case 106239.

Comment: That is true, will fix it now, thanks !

Comment: `n*n*n` can be written `n**3`

Comment: @hoosierEE, no, not in ES6, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 57 chars

```
def n(x:BigInt)=x.toString.toSet==(x*x*x).toString.toSet
```

Comment: I'm not fluent in Scala, but shouldn't it be possible to remove the whitespace around the various `=`s?

Comment: yes I'm new to code golf

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 69 bytes

This takes input from top of stack, and leaves a result on top of stack.  The result is the count of symmetric difference between the digit sets, so zero indicates true, and other numbers indicate false.

```dc
d[O~1r:ad0<f]dsfx+3^[O~1r:bd0<f]dsfxsaO[1-ddd;ar;b-d*la+sad0<m]dsmxla
```

### Explanation

Expanded version as commented full program with I/O to standard streams:

```dc
#!/usr/bin/dc

# read input
?

# store 1 in a[i] for each digit i
d[O~
  1r:a
  d0<f]dsfx
# cube the original number
+3^
# record its digits in b[]
[O~
 1r:b
 d0<f]dsfx

# 0 left on stack used to initialize accumulator
sa
# for i in 9..0, add (b[i]-a[i])^2
# accumulate in register 'a'
O[1-d
  dd;ar;b-d*
  la+sa
  d0<m]dsmx

# load result from accumulator
la

# print output
p
```

I hoped I could re-use the first function to store to both `a[]` and `b[]` but I couldn't find an easy way to do it.  Arrays can't be pushed or popped, and it was too hard to add an indirection to the function.

### Test results

Here's the test cases from the question, plus those suggested in comments:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 0
10 -> 0
107624 -> 0
251894 -> 0
251895 -> 4
102343 -> 6
106239 -> 1
2103869 -> 0
```

And here's the first 50 terms of [A029795](https://oeis.org/A029795), of 536 that I identified with this program by testing the numbers up to ten million:

```
0
1
10
100
1000
10000
100000
107624
109573
132485
138624
159406
165640
192574
205738
215806
251894
281536
318725
419375
427863
568314
642510
713960
953867
954086
963218
965760
1000000
1008529
1023479
1023674
1026258
1028537
1028565
1028756
1032284
1035743
1037689
1039725
1045573
1046783
1062851
1062854
1063279
1063724
1066254
1072399
1073824
1076240
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 87 bytes

Inspired by @Yodle, but I can't put a comment on his answer because I lack the reputation, I just parsed the string in a separate variable, this saves 5 characters:

```
var n=long.Parse(i);return new HashSet<char>(i).SetEquals(new HashSet<char>(n*n*n+""));
```

Comment: Can you strip the spaces around `=`?

Comment: thanks @Oliver, how do I count the bytes?

Comment: I used [this site.](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#var%20n%3Dlong.Parse%28i%29%3Breturn%20new%20HashSet%3Cchar%3E%28i%29.SetEquals%28new%20HashSet%3Cchar%3E%28n%2an%2an%2B%22%22%29%29%3B)

Comment: Are you missing an using to generic namespace?

Comment: @LinkNg what exactly are the requirements, I tried to find it on the website but couldn't.

Comment: From [this meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/383) and the links therein, the program/function should be compilable. In C# you need to add `using System.Collections.Generic;`, or qualify both `HashSet<char>` to be `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<char>`, or [put your program/function in this namespace](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184/60948), or [use using alias](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26978/60948). TBH I found it challenging to golf in C# while considering namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 15 bytes

I know it's not the best answer, but it is my first one:

```
l:Fi3#s$L|FL|$=
```

Explanation:

```
l            Read input
 :F          Put it in the var F
  i          Convert to int
   3#        Raise to the 3rd power
    s        Back to a string
     $       Sort
      L|     Remove dupes
       FL|   Remove dupes from the original input
        $    Sort
         =   Check if they are equal
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [MKSH](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) (BASH) ,3̶9̶ 4̶1̶ 3̶6̶ 5̶2̶  46 bytes

### (38 bytes without printing return value)

3g.sh:

```
c=`bc<<<$1^3`;[ ${c//[$1]}${1//[$c]} ];echo $?
```

Usage from file:

```
$ mksh 3g.sh 100
1
$ mksh 3g.sh 11                                        
0
$ mksh 3g.sh 251894                                    
1
```

Or from command line displaying return value outside (**38 bytes**):

```
$ mksh -c 'c=`bc<<<$0^3`;[ ${c//[$0]}${0//[$c]} ]' 2103869;echo $?
1
$ mksh -c 'c=`bc<<<$0^3`;[ ${c//[$0]}${0//[$c]} ]' 102343;echo $?
0
$ mksh -c 'c=`bc<<<$0^3`;[ ${c//[$0]}${0//[$c]} ]' 106239;echo $?
0
```

My question: is my 2nd oneliner a valid solution? The result should be printed on terminal or is it enough in an invisible return value? ( I'm new to codegolf. )

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You don't get to define what is true and false. Generally, `1` is true, and `0` is false. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey

Comment: So, then i have to add 2 more bytes. :-/

Comment: @mbomb007 But this is Bash. Bash defines 0 as truthy and everything else as falsy. And the meta question you link seems to agree with me: truthy and falsy should be understood relative to the language.

Comment: Then perhaps the answer body should be edited to clarify that.

Comment: does not work for 106239

Comment: @zeppelin: corrected

Comment: @Ipor 106239 still returns 1, 106239^3=
1199090390129919 (note the lack of "6")

Comment: @zeppelin: auch, thx! I misunderstood the task a bit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Convex](http://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 6 bytes

```
3#sê^!
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=MyNzw6peIQ&input=&args=MTA3NjI0)

Well, I guess major bugs in some operators can help in golfing sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2,  <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```
lambda x:set(`x`)==set(str(x**3))
```

Can't use backticks (`repr`) on large numbers because it includes the `'L'`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 61 Bytes

```
n=input()
print([i for i in str(int(n)**3)if i not in n]==[])
```

Or in python 2 (60 Bytes):

```
n=input()
print[i for i in str(n**3) if i not in str(n)]==[]
```

Comment: This would be shorter as a lambda: `lambda n:[i for i in str(n**3) if i not in str(n)]==[]`

Comment: @Oliver I haven't used lambda much before, so I don't know much about how to use it. However, I will bear this in mind if I need it for a future challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
V3esuFsux#
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@x9mnFpc6lZcWqH8//9/I1NDC0sTAA)

Like most other answers here, it just generates sets for both numbers and checks for equality:

```
     \ Implicit: Input on stack 1
V    \ Copy into stack 2
3e   \ Cube (stack 1)
su   \ Split into digits and create sorted set
Fsu  \ ^ Do the same to the second stack (not cubed)
x#   \ Check cross-stack equality and output (0 or 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell 3+, 72

```
filter f{"$("$_"[0..99]|sort -u)"}(($a=[long]$args[0])|f)-eq($a*$a*$a|f)
```

Pretty much the same solution idea as [TimmyD](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99797/15) had, just a lot shorter (and arrived at independently). I also think there aren't that many more *obvious* PowerShell solutions to this.

Comment: You should specify that this is v3+ for the `-Unique` parameter on the `Sort-Object`. Otherwise, nice tricks.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica 31 Bytes

```
(f=Sign@*DigitCount)@#==f[#^3]&
```

because `Sign<Union` and `DigitCount<IntegerDigits`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 8 bytes

```
Đ³ąỤ⇹ąỤ\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRDm4@0Pty95FH7TjAd8/@/oYEBAA)

Outputs an empty list if true

```
Đ³ąỤ⇹ąỤ\
            Implicit input
Đ           Duplicate input
 ³          Cube
  ą         Make array of digits
   Ụ        Filter so you have no duplicates
    ⇹       swap
     ąỤ     make array of digits and filter duplicates
       \    set difference
```

Comment: This fails for 106239.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
d.&^₃dp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompkcdy5VKikpTlfRqQMy0xJziVKXa04vK/6foqcU9ampOKfj/P9pAx1DHEEgYmJsZmegYmRpaWEIpU6CgkbGJcSwA)

-2 bytes thanks to Fatalize for fixing the interaction between zero and `p`.

The predicate succeeds if the input has the same set of digits as its cube, and fails otherwise. If run as a standalone program, success prints `true.` and failure prints `false.`

```
d          The input with duplicates removed
 .         is the output variable  
  &^₃      and the input cubed
     d     with duplicates removed
      p    is a permutation of the output variable.
```

Comment: The interaction between `0` and `p` has been fixed in [the latest commit](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/commit/c4894979fe4895c7315d4fd7312a4228fdcab19f). The 7 bytes `d.&^₃dp` should now work properly (once the commit is pulled on TIO).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 35 bytes

```
n->(d=i->Set(digits(i)))(n)==d(n^3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYrBCsIwEER/ZelpFxJok1btIfkJj6JQiC0LsixpLn59TA7CwJs3jG6Z7aF1hwBVbMQU2Mb7u2Dig8uJTEQoFEJCeXmqm@rniwI2gmaW0urQZYC93cjAYzQwtXSM14ubDbhluq1/Ln13fvZPqj8)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
ⁿαÉ▒▀z=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9R4/5zGw93Ppo26dG0hirb//8NuAy5DIGEgbmZkQmXkamhhSWQMjQwtjCz5DLiMuYyAcoZGZsYAykzI2NLiBJTAA)

-2 bytes thanks to KevinCruijssen. By changing the map to a for loop, we save one byte from not having to do a map (`m`), and another byte from not having to dump the array onto the stack (`~`).

### Explanation

```
ⁿ         pop a : push(a*a*a)
 α        wrap last two elements in array
  É       start block of length 3
   ▒      split to list of chars/digits
    ▀     unique elements of string/list
     z    reverse sort(array)
      =   pop(a, b), push(a==b)
```

Comment: Ah, hadn't noticed there was already a MathGolf answer. I've deleted mine again. You can golf 2 bytes with [`ⁿαÉ▒▀z=`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9R4/5zGw93Ppo26dG0hirb//8NuAy5DIGEgbmZkQmXkamhhSWQMjQwtjCz5DLiMuYyAcoZGZsYAykzI2NLiBJTAA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Even I had forgotten about this answer, good catch!

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
¤=ȯOud¹^3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9AS2xPr/UtTDu2MM/7//7@RqaGFpSkA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-!`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
³skU
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LSE&code=s3NrVQ&input=MTAw)

```
³skU     :Implicit input of integer U
³        :Cubed
 s       :Convert to string
  kU     :Remove all digits that appear in U
         :Convert to integer, resulting in NaN if all digits were removed
         :Implicit output of negation of result
```

Comment: What does the ! Flag do?

Comment: Negates the output, @Razetime.

Comment: This fails for 106239.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

```
.~3?^!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X6/O2D5O8f9/QwMjYxNjAA)

```
.        # Copy the input                "102343" "102343"
 ~       # Parse it to an integer        "102343" 102343
  3?     # Cube it                       "102343" 1071949756947607
    ^    # Get the different digits      "237956"
     !   # Is it an empty string?        0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
³ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCMyVFMSVCOCU4RCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwVHJ1ZSUwQTElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwVHJ1ZSUwQTEwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwLSUzRSUyMFRydWUlMEExMDc2MjQlMjAtJTNFJTIwVHJ1ZSUwQTI1MTg5NCUyMC0lM0UlMjBUcnVlJTBBMjUxODk1JTIwLSUzRSUyMEZhbHNlJTBBMTAyMzQzJTIwLSUzRSUyMEZhbHNlJmZsYWdzPUMh)

Output with inverted booleans - add the `!` flag to take the logical NOT of the result.

##### Explanation

```python
    # Implicit input
³   # Cube it
 ḍ  # Symmetric set difference
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 9 bytes

Hopefully can take another char off.

```
@I.{`^Q3`
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40I.%7B%60%5EQ3%60&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A10%0A107624%0A251894%0A251895%0A102343&debug=0).

```
!          Negation, tells if set is empty
 -         Setwise subtraction
  `^Q3     String repr of input^3
  `        String repr of implicit input
```

Comment: This fails for input **106239**.

Answer (score 0):

### C#6, <s>117</s> <s>118</s> 115 bytes

```
using System.Linq;bool A(ulong n){string s=n+"",t=n*n*n+"";return s.All(x=>t.Contains(x))&t.All(x=>s.Contains(x));}
```

Praise [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

+1 byte due to `long` range problem
-3 bytes by storing strings to variable

Ungolfed + explanations

```
bool A(ulong n)
{
    // Convert n and n^3 to strings
    string s=n+"",t=n*n*n+"";
    // Two sets are equal iff:
    // Foreach element in one set, it is also present in another set
    return s.All(x=>t.Contains(x))&t.All(x=>s.Contains(x));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 48 bytes

```
<?=($f=count_chars)($a=$argv[1],3)==$f($a**3,3);
```

It's the first time I've assigned a function to a variable like this and I'm honestly quite surprised that it works.

Comment: It works in PHP 7, yes, not in PHP 5. Also, this throws a notice because `count_chars` should be in apostrophes or double quotes. https://3v4l.org/UsWn4

Comment: @chx I know, what I was really surprised about was being able to do it in line. As for the notice, ignoring notices is standard practise in PPCG and learning what strings you can use without the quotes is a decent start for golfing PHP.

Comment: 45 +1 bytes with `-F` flag and `$argn` instead of `$argv[1]`

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 12 bytes

```
3ßⁿk`$╔S`Mi=
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=M8Of4oG_a2Ak4pWUU2BNaT0&input=MTA3NjI0)

Explanation:

```
3ßⁿk`$╔S`Mi=
3ßⁿ           copy of input, cubed
   k          [input, input**3]
    `$╔S`M    for each:
     $          stringify
      ╔         remove duplicate elements
       S        sort
          i=  flatten and compare equality
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 18 bytes

```
-:&(/:~)&~.&":^&3x
```

I think this is the most`&`s I've used in an answer to date. This is a fork:

```
-:&(/:~)&~.&": ^&3x
```

The verb on the right, `^&3x`, raises the argument to the `3`rd power, converting to an e`x`tended number if necessary. Then, the verb on the left takes right arg (cubed arg) and left arg (arg). `&` applies the verb following to each argument, then passes each argument to the preceding function. So, this is:

```
-:&(/:~)&~.&":
            ":  string representation
         ~.     unique elements
   (/:~)        sorted
-:              are the same
```

### Test cases

```
   f=:-:&(/:~)&~.&":^&3x
   (,. f"0) 0 1 10 107624 251894 251895 102343
     0 1
     1 1
    10 1
107624 1
251894 1
251895 0
102343 0
   f 251894
1
   f 251895
0
```

Comment: Holy... this was the best I could do: `(]([=(~.@,)&.":)[:x:3^~])` (25 bytes, or 23 if you don't count the parens)

Answer (score 0):

## Julia 40 bytes

```
 h(x)= ==(Set.(digits.([x,big(x)^3]))...)
```

Test:

```
h.([0,1,10,107624,251894,251895,102343,106239,2103869])
9-element Array{Bool,1}:
  true
  true
  true
  true
  true
 false
 false
 false
  true
```

Comment: `big(x)` requires few bytes than `Int128(x)`

Comment: thanks, i forgot `big` was availble as a function (rather than just as a string macro)

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 34 bytes

```
!n=symdiff("$n",dec(big(n)^3))==[]
```

How does it work? Well, strings act like arrays in many ways, so we can apply the `symdiff` (symmetric difference) function to a pair of strings to get an array of all characters found in only one of the two strings. If that is an empty array (`[]`), then the set of digits is the same.

`big` is used to make sure it handles larger values of `n^3` (anything that would overflow in 64 bit), although it will still be limited in terms of `n` itself (but easily covers the range required).

Answer (score 0):

**C#**

Without any 32 or 64 bit limits...

```
Func<BigInteger,bool> x = n => !(n * n * n + "").Except(n + "").Any();
```

Comment: You can drop the function name and type signature - [unnamed lambdas are acceptable](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9032/45941). Additionally, you have a lot of whitespace that can be removed. Remember, in code golf, you're trying to make your code as short as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Mego, I saw this question at *Hot Network Questions* But I think I have to read some docs before posting next answer...

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 10 bytes

This answer uses the direct approach, using `str(), sort(), uniq()` on `n` then `n**3` directly. Golfing suggestions welcome! [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=JFPilZQzw5_igb8kU-KVlD0&input=MTA3NjI0)

```
$S╔3ßⁿ$S╔=
```

**Ungolfing**

```
      Implicit input n.
$S╔   str(), sort(), uniq() on n.
3ßⁿ   Push n**3.
$S╔   str(), sort(), uniq() on n**3.
=     Check if the results are equal.
      Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 0):

## bash, 42

```
[[ $1 = +([$((a=$1**3))])&&$a = +([$1]) ]]
```

Comment: test with 2103869

Comment: @IporSircer plenty of other answers are limited by the language's limits

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 34 bytes

```
i=>s"$i".toSet==(""+(i*i*i)).toSet
```

Usage:

```
val f:(BigInt=>Boolean)=...
print(f(2103869))
```

Explanation:

```
i=>            //define an anonymous function with a parameter i
    s"$i"        //use string interpolation to convert i to a string
    .toSet       //convert the string to a set of chars
  ==           //is it equal to...
    (            
    ""+(i*i*i)   //i*i*i as a string
    ).toSet      //as a set of chars
```

Answer (score 0):

### Matlab/Octave, 39 bytes

```
a=@(x)(unique(num2str(x)));min(a(x)==a(x^3))
```

Comment: `==` will give an error if the numbers of unique digits are different  (maybe use `isequal`). Also, this would require `x` to be of type `uint64` in order to work across the specified input range; you should indicate it in your answer. You can remove the parentheses around `unique`. In addition, the general rule is that your code should be a full program or a function (i.e. define the second part as an anonymous function or use `input()`).

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3, 75 bytes

```
func a(n:UInt64){print(Set("\(n)".characters)==Set("\(n*n*n)".characters))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, <s>92</s> 76 bytes

```
g(y:String):String==removeDuplicates(sort(y));f(x)==(g(x)=g((x^3)))::Boolean
```

results

```
->[i,f(i)] for i in [0,1,10,107624,251894,251895,102343,106239]

  [[0,true], [1,true], [10,true], [107624,true], [251894,true],
   [251895,false], [102343,false], [106239,false]]
```

Comment: This produces a false positive for 106239 (the Dennis test case).

Comment: @zeppelin ok i wrote a new version... thank you

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 88 bytes

```
lambda n:reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,map(lambda x:x[0]in str(x[1]),[(i,n)for i in str(n**3)]))
```

Worked in version 2.7.9.

This lambda `lambda x:x[0]in str(x[1])` receives a tuple, which first element is an char and the second element is a integer. This function checks if the char is in the string correspondent to the integer.

This `[(i,n)for i in str(n**3)]` creates a set of arguments, for each character of the string of n³, and function  `map` evaluates the lambda function for each argument of the set. Then, the result is a list of booleans that tell if each character of the string of n³ is in the string of n. The reduce and the lambda `reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,...)` multiplies all the elements of the list, returning 1 if all the characters of the string of n³ are in the string of n and 0 otherwise.

A 89 bytes solution with a similar idea but with different implementation is:

```
lambda n:len(filter(lambda x:x[0]in str(x[1]),[(i,n)for i in str(n**3)]))==len(str(n**3))
```

Here, `filter` literally filter the elements of the set of arguments that leads the internal lambda function to returns True. The resulting list has its length compared to the length of the string of n³ to check if all the characters of the string of n³ are in the string of n.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 109 bytes

```clojure
(use '[clojure.string :only(split)])#(if(= (into #{}(split(str %)#""))(into #{}(split(str(* % % %))#"")))1 0)
```

Use the function like this:

```
...(#(...) 106239)
```

Yikes, that is a long one-liner.

Ungolfed:

```clojure
(use '[clojure.string :only (split)])
(defn cube [n]
  (if (= (into #{} (split (str n) #""))
         (into #{} (split (str(* n n n)) #"")))
    1 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL NARS 29 chars

```
{(⍵>2e6)∨⍵<0:¯1⋄''≡(⍕⍵)§⍕⍵*3}
```

f has meaningful result only if 0<=arg<=2000000 else if arg>=2098567 (so i wrote 2000000 for round)
it miss digits as float with result can not be meaningful...So if arg of f is out 0<=arg<=2000000
it return the error number ¯1

```
  f←{(⍵>2e6)∨⍵<0:¯1⋄''≡(⍕⍵)§⍕⍵*3} 
  f¨ 0 1 10 107624 251894 251895 102343      
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
  f 2000000
0
  f 2000001
¯1
  f ¯9
¯1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure 35 bytes

```
#(every?(set(str %))(str(* % % %)))
```

Same byte count as an earlier answer, but slightly different approach.

More obscure but unfortunately longer:

```
#(apply =(map(comp set str)[%(* % % %)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 15 bytes

```
/D.n~@
\iXDo/3E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fRS@vzoErJjPCJV/f2PX/fyNDA2MLM0sA)

Prints `Jabberwocky` as a truthy result and nothing as a falsy result (Alice's canonical truthy and falsy values in Ordinal mode).

#### Explanation

```
/   Switch to Ordinal mode.
i   Read all input as a string.
.D  Duplicate the string and then deduplicate the characters of the copy,
    turning it into the set of digits.
~   Swap with the other copy.
/   Switch to Cardinal mode.
3E  Implicitly convert the string to the represented integer value N and raise
    it to the third power.
\   Switch to Ordinal mode.
D   Implicitly convert N^3 to a string and deduplicate its characters as well.
X   Symmetric multiset difference. Gives an empty string iff both strings 
    are permutations of each other. The fact that Alice only has multiset
    oprations is the reason why we needed to use D on both strings.
n   Logical NOT. Turns the empty string into the (truthy) "Jabberwocky"
    and everything else into the (falsy) empty string.
o   Output the result.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 12 bytes

```
L,d3^BD€q=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HJ8U4zsnlUdOaQtv/KjmJuUkpiQqGdgpgYMBprRBSVJrK5c@FLmWIU8oQuy5DA3MzIxOsUkamhhaWeKRMgVJuiTnFGCYaGZsY45IzMzK2RMj9BwA)

### How it works

```
L,		; Define a lambda function
		; Example argument:         [106239]
	d3^	; Push n³;          STACK = [106239 1199090390129919]
	BD	; Get the digits;   STACK = [[1 0 6 2 3 9] [1 1 9 9 0 9 0 3 9 0 1 2 9 9 1 9]]
	€q	; Deduplicate €ach; STACK = [{0 1 2 3 6 9} {0 1 2 3 9}]
	=	; Equal?	    STACK = [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
à±▒!⌂▼▒RÜ
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C3%A0%C2%B1%E2%96%92%21%E2%8C%82%E2%96%BC%E2%96%92R%C3%9C&i=0%0A1%0A10%0A107624%0A251894%0A251895%0A102343%0A106239&a=1&m=2)

### Explanation

Uses the unpacked version to explain.

```
cJ*EuxEu|n!
cJ*            Raise to 3rd power (can also be `3|*`)
   Eu          Discrete digits
     xEu       Discrete digits of input
        |n!    Array xnor
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES7, 48 bytes from Downgoat 's

```js
F=
n=>(f=s=>[...new Set(s+f)].sort()+f)(n)==f(n**3)

console.log([0,1,10,107624,251894,251895,102343].map(F))
```